# Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?

Tags: javascript, html, url, data-uri, save-as

If for example you follow the link:

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64,SGVsbG8=
```

The browser will prompt you to download a file consisting of the data held as base64 in the hyperlink itself.  Is there any way of suggesting a default name in the markup?  If not, is there a JavaScript solution?

Comment: maybe unrelated to this issue but I suggest using blob's & URL.createObjectURL if this isn't an server or old browser obstacle

Comment: Some browsers support the mediatype's optional parameter "name": `data:application/pdf;name=document.pdf;base64,BASE64_DATA_ENCODED`

Comment: I had the issue with Firefox pdf.js which tends to hang in some cases if it cannot extract a filename from the data uri. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585921/firefox-hangs-when-displaying-a-pdf-via-data-url/45585922#45585922

Comment: @mems Which browsers support the "name" parameter? Can you point me to some reference documentation? (my google-fu has failed me).

Comment: @DimuDesigns At least Firefox at that time. It look like it's not anymore the case. It's related to MIME Content-Type (!= Content-Disposition) "name" parameter (not in RFC?)

Comment: Is it works for blob uri?. [How to set the download file extension for blob data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71686536/6521116)

Answer (score 218):

Use the `download` attribute:

```
<a download='FileName' href='your_url'>
```

[The `download` attribute works on](http://caniuse.com/#search=download) Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera, desktop Safari 10+, iOS Safari 13+, and not IE11.

Comment: This answer is the only complete one. No you can't do it with data: URI. Yes you can provide a file name to a download link with pure Javascript. Thanks!

Comment: @BioDesign: It works even with data:URI's in chrome. See: http://jsfiddle.net/pYpqW/

Comment: but you can’t do it with `window.location.replace`. if you e.g. want to create a data:uri or one generated by [`window.URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/window.URL.createObjectURL), and download that as file, you’ll have to create an <a> and click it: http://jsfiddle.net/flyingsheep/wpQtH/ (no, `$(...).click()` doesn’t work)

Comment: It's a WHATWG feature that Google implements, but since it's an (unofficial) standard it could get popular. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download

Comment: @flyingsheep `$('<a href="data:text/plain,Test" download="test.txt">')[0].click()` seems to work fine here (Chrome 23) (note: I **used the native `click` method**, not jQuery's one). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2zsRW/

Comment: but in firefox, only http://jsfiddle.net/2zsRW/1/ works. maybe some sort of same-origin-policy or bug? (an aside: since the download attribute is not yet implemented, it just replaces the frame there instead of downloading)

Comment: @flyingsheep it seems they are enforcing a same-origin policy in Firefox "In Firefox 20 this attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a In my testing, Chrome doesn't have this limitation.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the file **_will_** be downloaded if the user clicks on the link. What if you just want to specify the filename if the user does right-click + Save Link As...?

Comment: I try to use the `download` for the blob data. But it not works. [How to set the download file extension for blob data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71686536/6521116)

Answer (score 71):

Chrome makes this very simple these days:

```
function saveContent(fileContents, fileName)
{
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = fileName;
    link.href = 'data:,' + fileContents;
    link.click();
}
```

Comment: Refer to [http://caniuse.com/#feat=download](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) for a complete list of browser compatibility.

Comment: @tixastronauta: Despite the info in that page, not working in my firefox 44. Working nicely in Chrome. 48

Comment: there is a bit better way, cuz via this you can't save divided into paragraphs text file. 

my variant is:
`var file = new File(rows, "file.csv", {type: 'text/csv'});

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
link.download = file.name;
link.click();`

i've found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Comment: Unfortunately this is the same 2 MB limit in Chrome when used with a data URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755526/1024735

Answer (score 62):

**HTML only:** use the `download` attribute:

```html
<a download="logo.gif" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">Download transparent png</a>
```

---

**Javascript only:** you can save any data URI with this code:

```js
function saveAs(uri, filename) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
    link.href = uri;
    link.download = filename;

    //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    
    //simulate click
    link.click();

    //remove the link when done
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  } else {
    window.open(uri);
  }
}

var file = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7'
saveAs(file, 'logo.gif');
```

**Chrome, Firefox, and Edge 13+** will use the specified filename.

**IE11, Edge 12, and Safari 9** (which [don't support the `download` attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)) will download the file with their default name **or they will simply display it** in a new tab, if it's of a supported file type: images, videos, audio files, …

Comment: For a more complete solution, I suggest using [`downloadjs` on npm](https://github.com/rndme/download)

Comment: It works for me but the browser page refreshes after that. Wonder how to prevent that?

Comment: Doesn't work in chrome for file size > 2MB due restriction by chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695151/data-protocol-url-size-limitations

Comment: The limit belongs to the `data:` URI, which is what the question mentions. This answer also works with Blobs and whatever else has a URI

Answer (score 42):

According to [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397), no, there isn't.

<strike>Nor does there appear to be any [attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) of the `<a>` element that you can use either.</strike>

However HTML5 has subsequently introduced the [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) attribute on the `<a>` element, although at the time of writing support is not universal (no MSIE support, for example)

Comment: If the file is so long the download fails

Comment: If anyone is wondering about support, [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)'s the caniuse page for this feature

Answer (score 21):

I've looked a bit in firefox sources in netwerk/protocol/data/nsDataHandler.cpp

data handler only parses content/type and charset, and looks if there is ";base64"
in the string

the rfc specifices no filename and at least firefox handles no filename for it,
the code generates a random name plus ".part"

I've also checked firefox log

```
[b2e140]: DOCSHELL 6e5ae00 InternalLoad data:application/octet-stream;base64,SGVsbG8=
[b2e140]: Found extension '' (filename is '', handling attachment: 0)
[b2e140]: HelperAppService::DoContent: mime 'application/octet-stream', extension ''
[b2e140]: Getting mimeinfo from type 'application/octet-stream' ext ''
[b2e140]: Extension lookup on '' found: 0x0
[b2e140]: Ext. lookup for '' found 0x0
[b2e140]: OS gave back 0x43609a0 - found: 0
[b2e140]: Searched extras (by type), rv 0x80004005
[b2e140]: MIME Info Summary: Type 'application/octet-stream', Primary Ext ''
[b2e140]: Type/Ext lookup found 0x43609a0
```

interesting files if you want to look at mozilla sources:

```
data uri handler: netwerk/protocol/data/nsDataHandler.cpp
where mozilla decides the filename: uriloader/exthandler/nsExternalHelperAppService.cpp
InternalLoad string in the log: docshell/base/nsDocShell.cpp
```

I think you can stop searching a solution for now, because I suspect there is none :)

as noticed in this thread html5 has `download` attribute, it works also on firefox 20 http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download

Answer (score 16):

The following Javascript snippet works in Chrome by using the new 'download' attribute of links and simulating a click.

```
function downloadWithName(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  link.click();
}
```

And the following example shows it's use:

```
downloadWithName("data:,Hello%2C%20World!", "helloWorld.txt")
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox, I added an extended answer below with Fx compatibility.

Answer (score 12):

No.

The entire purpose is that it's a datastream, not a file. The data source should not have any knowledge of the user agent handling it as a file... and it doesn't.

Comment: The purpose of `data:` is to fudge a block of _internal_ data into URL format without having to _read_ it from a protocol-based source. The link in @silex's answer shows that the ability to suggest a preferred name to _write_ it to is considered useful, even if it's not implemented yet.

Comment: @Alnitak: Useful? Absolutely. Technically appropriate? Still not convinced. :)

Comment: @Tomalak consider the difference between loading the data and saving it - just because a blob is encoded inline in a data: URL doesn't mean that it shouldn't have a preferred name for saving it to.

Comment: @Alnitak: The data itself should have no knowledge of how you load _or_ save it. It's data.

Comment: But your line about it's "entire purpose" is wrong.  `data:` was specifically invented to allow (small) _inline_ content to appear in a fudged-together URL format so that it could be used by things like image tags without a separate HTTP request. HTML says the content of a `img src` attribute must be a URL, so that's what RFC 2397 created.  There is no "data source".

Comment: @Alnitak: Exactly. There's no data source. There's no context. The URI _is_ the data.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Saving an empty file with the URI as the filename would make more sense right? Btw, We have `URL.createObjectURL` to make things even worse.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: If you need a filename, yeah. Otherwise best to save the HTTP request.

Answer (score 11):

you can add a download attribute to the anchor element.

sample:

```
<a download="abcd.cer"
    href="data:application/stream;base64,MIIDhTC......">down</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

Using [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker_API/Using_Service_Workers), this is finally possible in the truest sense.

1. Create a fake URL. For example /saveAs/myPrettyName.jpg
2. Use URL in `<a href, <img src`, window.open( url ), absolutely anything that can be done with a "real" URL.
3. Inside the worker, catch the fetch event, and respond with the correct data.

The browser will now suggest myPrettyName.jpg even if the user opens the file in a new tab, and tries to save it there. It will be exactly as if the file had come from the server.

```
// In the service worker
self.addEventListener( 'fetch', function(e)
{
    if( e.request.url.startsWith( '/blobUri/' ) )
    {
        // Logic to select correct dataUri, and return it as a Response
        e.respondWith( dataURLAsRequest );
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting! Support seems to be quite shallow for now, though: http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers

Answer (score 5):

Look at this link:
http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/uri/2010Feb/0069.html

Quote:

> It even works (as in, doesn't cause a problem) with ;base64 at the end
>   like this (in Opera at least):
>
> **data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;headers=Content-Disposition%3A%20attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22with%20spaces.txt%22%0D%0AContent-Language%3A%20en;base64,4oiaDQo%3D**

Also there is some info in the rest messages of the discussion.

Comment: unfortunately this does not download.

Comment: this discussion was for a _proposed_ extension to the data URI format - it hasn't been implemented.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tiny workaround script on Google Code that worked for me:

http://code.google.com/p/download-data-uri/

It adds a form with the data in it, submits it and then removes the form again. Hacky, but it did the job for me. Requires jQuery.

This thread showed up in Google before the Google Code page and I thought it might be helpful to have the link in here, too.

Comment: Interesting script but it does require the server to get the response ans send it back right? http://jsfiddle.net/hZySf/

Comment: I'm not sure where the file is being generated from.. is that file being stored in the base64 encode? (I'm not too familiar with base64)

Comment: @streetlight: The "file" (i.e. data) is generated by Javascript.  The context of that project (and probably most here) assume that you have some way of getting your desired data into a JS variable.  The difference is that instead of presenting it to the user via a `data:...` URI, that script creates a form to POST it to the server.  And the server then presumably echoes it straight back as an HTTP "download" response (i.e. with an appropriate Content-Disposition header specifying the filename).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a jQuery version based off of Holf's version and works with Chrome and Firefox whereas his version seems to only work with Chrome.  It's a little strange to add something to the body to do this but if someone has a better option I'm all for it.

```
var exportFileName = "export-" + filename;
$('<a></a>', {
    "download": exportFileName,
    "href": "data:," + JSON.stringify(exportData, null,5),
    "id": "exportDataID"
}).appendTo("body")[0].click().remove();
```

Comment: With jQuery 1.11 I get an exception because of the .remove(). I got around this by assigning `$().appendTo()` to a variable then calling `variable.click(); variable.remove()`

Comment: @p0lar_bear you should get that exception with any jQuery, because getting the `[0]` from any "jQuery element" should return the first DOM element it represents, which essentially "takes you out of" jQuery.

Comment: You actually shouldn't need to append/remove the element at all -- see comments at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17311705/1037948

Answer (score 2):

This one works with Firefox 43.0 (older not tested):

**dl.js:**

```
function download() {
  var msg="Hello world!";
  var blob = new File([msg], "hello.bin", {"type": "application/octet-stream"});

  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  window.location.href=a;
}
```

**dl.html**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dl.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="create" type="button" onclick="download();">Download</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If button is clicked it offered a file named *hello.bin* for download. Trick is to use *File* instead of *Blob*.

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/File

Answer (score 1):

(This answer has been made deprecated by newer technology, but will be kept here for historical interest.)

<strike>It's kind of hackish, but I've been in the same situation before. I was dynamically generating a text file in javascript and wanted to provide it for download by encoding it with the data-URI.</strike>

This is possible with <strike>minor</strike>major user intervention. Generate a link `<a href="data:...">right-click me and select "Save Link As..." and save as "example.txt"</a>`. As I said, this is inelegant, but it works if you do not need a professional solution.

This could be made less painful by using flash to copy the name into the clipboard first. Of course if you let yourself use Flash or Java (now with less and less browser support I think?), you could probably find a another way to do this.

Comment: This is not a solution and does not meet what was asked for. Sorry.

Comment: Lol @ "minor user intervention". Getting the user to do the whole thing for you is not "minor user intervention".

Comment: Combine this with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311645/download-image-with-javascript to trigger the generated link and you don't need user intervention.  You can specify the [HTML5 `download` attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute) to suggest a name as mentioned by [many](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6943481/1037948) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16523173/1037948) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21915171/1037948).

Comment: This is a great workaround for Safari.  Use Modernizr to detect when the download attribute is not supported and update the link text!

Answer (score 0):

`<a href=.. download=.. >` works for left-click and right-click -> save link as..,

but `<img src=.. download=.. >` doesn't work for right-click -> save image as.. , "Download.jped" is suggested.

If you combine both:`<a href=.. download=..><img src=..></a>`

it works for left-click, right-click -> save link as.., right-click -> save image as..

You have to write the data-uri twice (href and src), so for large image files it is better to copy the uri with javascript.

*tested with Chrome/Edge 88*

Answer (score -1):

```
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6
var sessionId ='\n';
var token = '\n';
var caseId = CaseIDNumber + '\n';
var url = casewebUrl+'\n';
var uri = sessionId + token + caseId + url;//data in file
var fileName = "file.i4cvf";// any file name with any extension
if (isIE)
    {
            var fileData = ['\ufeff' + uri];
            var blobObject = new Blob(fileData);
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, fileName);
    }
    else //chrome
    {
        window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
         window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, function (fs) {
            fs.root.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function (fileEntry) { 
                fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                    var fileData = ['\ufeff' + uri];
                    var blob = new Blob(fileData);
                    fileWriter.addEventListener("writeend", function () {
                        var fileUrl = fileEntry.toURL();
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = fileUrl;
                        link.download = fileName;
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();
                        document.body.removeChild(link);
                    }, false);
                    fileWriter.write(blob);
                }, function () { });
            }, function () { });
         }, function () { });
    }
```

Comment: pls add a more detailed explanation to your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: this answer is garbage

Answer (score -2):

You actually can achieve this, in Chrome and FireFox.

Try the following url, it will download the code that was used.

```
data:text/html;base64,PGEgaHJlZj0iZGF0YTp0ZXh0L2h0bWw7YmFzZTY0LFBHRWdhSEpsWmowaVVGVlVYMFJCVkVGZlZWSkpYMGhGVWtVaUlHUnZkMjVzYjJGa1BTSjBaWE4wTG1oMGJXd2lQZ284YzJOeWFYQjBQZ3BrYjJOMWJXVnVkQzV4ZFdWeWVWTmxiR1ZqZEc5eUtDZGhKeWt1WTJ4cFkyc29LVHNLUEM5elkzSnBjSFErIiBkb3dubG9hZD0idGVzdC5odG1sIj4KPHNjcmlwdD4KZG9jdW1lbnQucXVlcnlTZWxlY3RvcignYScpLmNsaWNrKCk7Cjwvc2NyaXB0Pg==
```