# Get window icon, put it on canvas, overlay image, save as ico (WinXP and Win7)

Tags: c++, canvas, firefox-addon, icons, jsctypes

Right now I change the icon of a window with [this code](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/33b6d28ebf4ff5ebdff6/5a5913201eb62470bde4ce2231b3373211507eef).

What I want to do though is get the current icon in use by a window. Then put it on a canvas. Then put another image on that (a badge) then save it as ico.

Comment: Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047470/wm-geticon-not-working-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried that, however the follow should work in general (with a lot of fiddling)

1. `WM_GETICON` to get the big and small icon.
2. Convert the icon to something the loader can understand (aka. either a BITMAP or ICO). E.g. [How can I save HICON to an .ico file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289894/how-can-i-save-hicon-to-an-ico-file)
3. Load the image. E.g. [Javascript: Render PNG stored as Uint8Array onto Canvas element without Data URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950865/javascript-render-png-stored-as-uint8array-onto-canvas-element-without-data-uri)
4. `canvas.drawImage`
5. `canvas.mozGetAsFile` (`Blob`) or `canvas.mozFetchAsStream` (`nsIInputStream`) using the `image/vnd.microsoft.icon` mime.
6. Take the resulting data and reconstruct an icon.
7. [`LookupIconIdFromDirectoryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CreateIconFromResourceEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
8. `WM_SETICON`

Comment: Thanks again man! I'll knock something up and report back. :)