# Get icon from a window in another application

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

Say I have some third-party Windows application running and displaying multiple windows. And all these windows have different icons. In my application I want to get a bitmap image of the icon used in any window of that application, given I have a window handle (HWND). This should be done dynamically, at runtime. How can this be done?

Comment: Note that WinAPI is plain c, please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The [WIL](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) is C++, though, and it is a very popular library for consuming the Win32 API. Plus, some parts of the API surface cannot reasonably be accessed from C (such as Direct2D). Nothing wrong with having the [tag:c++] tag here.

Comment: @ivan.ukr have you looked at [`WM_GETICON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-geticon) yet?

Comment: How about [EnumResource*(Ex)\[A/W\]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/enumerating-resources) functions?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I've seen WM_GETICON, but the whole question - does it work for the case when window that I will send it to is from another process?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT How does EnumResourceXXX will help? Please elaborate a bit more. You can even write answer if you think you have it.

Comment: @ivan.ukr supposedly yes (I haven't tried it). See this code: https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.ui/c/m9J7O_sIA1E/m/0EG-UUe8tFEJ

Comment: @RemyLebeau yup, it works.

Comment: @ivan.ukr what led me to that code is [this discussion](https://microsoft.public.vc.mfc.narkive.com/6l3OUc6A/get-icon-of-another-application). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24052117/65863) also helped, too.

Comment: @ivan.ukr, Would you answer yourself?