# Convert Windows HICON to raw data for display in html frontend

Tags: javascript, winapi, rust, tauri

I am making a window-switcherin tauri using Rust and solidjs.

I am using [winapi](https://docs.rs/winapi/latest/winapi/) to interact with Windows.

For now I have:

1. HashMap of <window_title (string), HWND >
2. I send the window titles to the frontend
3. When clicked, it correctly switches the windows.

I want to display the app icon beside its title, so it can be more recognizable.

This is my method:

```
unsafe extern "system" fn enum_windows_proc(hwnd: HWND, lparam: LPARAM) -> BOOL {
    let title_length = GetWindowTextLengthW(hwnd);
    if title_length > 0 {
        let mut buffer: Vec<u16> = vec![0; (title_length + 1) as usize]; // +1 for null terminator
        GetWindowTextW(hwnd, buffer.as_mut_ptr(), buffer.len() as i32);

        if IsWindowVisible(hwnd) != 0 {
            let window_title = OsString::from_wide(&buffer).to_string_lossy().to_string();
            let title_map = &mut *(lparam as *mut HashMap<String, (HWND, HICON)>);
            let app_icon = get_app_icon(hwnd);

            if app_icon.is_some() {
                title_map.insert(window_title, (hwnd, app_icon.unwrap()));
            }
        }
    }

    1
}

fn get_app_icon(hwnd: HWND) -> Option<HICON> {
    let icon_handle: usize = unsafe { GetClassLongPtrW(hwnd, GCLP_HICON as i32) };
    if icon_handle == 0 {
        None
    } else {
        Some(icon_handle as HICON)
    }
}
```

I modified it to have the icon beside the window handle

Is my method for retrieving the HICON correct? How can I log it? I tried to print the `icon_handle` but it shows nothing. But when I try to log any string in its place it logs correctly.

Comment: Does your `icon_handle` have some values? Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/24052117/15511041 work for you?

Comment: HICONs are opaque handles, you can get bitmap data out of them using the `GetIconInfo()` winapi function. Also note that icons can be assigned on a per-window basis - you should use `WM_GETICON` to query for a per-window icon before falling back to the class icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can convert `HICON` to a `base64` representation of `PNG` icon:

```rust
use base64::{engine::general_purpose, Engine as _};
use image::RgbaImage;
use std::{mem::{self, MaybeUninit},ptr::addr_of_mut};
use windows::Win32::{Foundation::HWND, Graphics::Gdi::{DeleteObject, GetDC, GetDIBits, GetObjectW, ReleaseDC, BITMAP, BITMAPINFOHEADER, BI_RGB,DIB_RGB_COLORS, HDC}, UI::WindowsAndMessaging::{GetIconInfo, HICON}};

unsafe fn icon_to_rgba_image(icon: HICON) -> String {
    let bitmap_size = i32::try_from(mem::size_of::<BITMAP>()).unwrap();
    let biheader_size = u32::try_from(mem::size_of::<BITMAPINFOHEADER>()).unwrap();

    let mut info = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    GetIconInfo(icon, info.as_mut_ptr()).unwrap();
    let info = info.assume_init_ref();
    DeleteObject(info.hbmMask).unwrap();

    let mut bitmap: MaybeUninit<BITMAP> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    let result = GetObjectW(
        info.hbmColor,
        bitmap_size,
        Some(bitmap.as_mut_ptr().cast()),
    );
    assert!(result == bitmap_size);
    let bitmap = bitmap.assume_init_ref();

    let width = u32::try_from(bitmap.bmWidth).unwrap();
    let height = u32::try_from(bitmap.bmHeight).unwrap();
    let w = usize::try_from(bitmap.bmWidth).unwrap();
    let h = usize::try_from(bitmap.bmHeight).unwrap();

    let buf_size = w
        .checked_mul(h)
        .and_then(|size| size.checked_mul(4))
        .unwrap();
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(buf_size);

    let dc = GetDC(HWND(0));
    assert!(dc != HDC(0));

    let mut bitmap_info = BITMAPINFOHEADER {
        biSize: biheader_size,
        biWidth: bitmap.bmWidth,
        biHeight: -bitmap.bmHeight,
        biPlanes: 1,
        biBitCount: 32,
        biCompression: BI_RGB,
        biSizeImage: 0,
        biXPelsPerMeter: 0,
        biYPelsPerMeter: 0,
        biClrUsed: 0,
        biClrImportant: 0,
    };
    let result = GetDIBits(
        dc,
        info.hbmColor,
        0,
        height,
        Some(buf.as_mut_ptr().cast()),
        addr_of_mut!(bitmap_info).cast(),
        DIB_RGB_COLORS,
    );
    buf.set_len(buf.capacity());

    let result = ReleaseDC(HWND(0), dc);
    assert!(result == 1);
    DeleteObject(info.hbmColor).unwrap();

    for chunk in buf.chunks_exact_mut(4) {
        let [b, _, r, _] = chunk else { unreachable!() };
        mem::swap(b, r);
    }

    let img = RgbaImage::from_vec(width, height, buf).unwrap();

    let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    img.write_to(&mut Cursor::new(&mut data), image::ImageOutputFormat::Png)?;

    general_purpose::STANDARD.encode(&data);
}
```

=============

So Tauri is built on top of [TAO](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tao), which is a fork of [winit](https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit) and they implement window management for each platform there.

Specifically [windows/window.rs](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tao/blob/dev/src/platform_impl/windows/window.rs), so in your case I would clone the TAO repository and add required changes there, and then [patch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html) your dependencies to make it point to your version of TAO.

Now, here's how TAO [implements](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tao/blob/dev/src/platform_impl/windows/window.rs#L1192-L1205) `hicon` related class:

```rust
let class = WNDCLASSEXW {
    cbSize: mem::size_of::<WNDCLASSEXW>() as u32,
    style: CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC,
    lpfnWndProc: Some(window_proc),
    cbClsExtra: 0,
    cbWndExtra: 0,
    hInstance: HINSTANCE(GetModuleHandleW(PCWSTR::null()).unwrap_or_default().0),
    hIcon: HICON::default(),
    hCursor: HCURSOR::default(), // must be null in order for cursor state to work properly
    hbrBackground: HBRUSH::default(),
    lpszMenuName: PCWSTR::null(),
    lpszClassName: PCWSTR::from_raw(class_name.as_ptr()),
    hIconSm: HICON::default(),
  };
```

Oh, it's worth mentioning, Tauri uses [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate, instead of `winapi`. Which has less downloads, but IMO better support from Microsoft. And essentially very similar to what [apple-sys](https://crates.io/crates/apple-sys) done for Macs.

As Jonathan Potter pointed out, you need to use [GetIconInfo](https://docs.rs/windows-sys/latest/windows_sys/Win32/UI/WindowsAndMessaging/fn.GetIconInfo.html) to get hicon info:

```rust
pub struct ICONINFO {
    pub fIcon: BOOL,
    pub xHotspot: u32,
    pub yHotspot: u32,
    pub hbmMask: HBITMAP,
    pub hbmColor: HBITMAP,
}
```

So to answer your original question, no you can't print `hicon` because it's just [a](https://docs.rs/windows-sys/latest/windows_sys/Win32/UI/WindowsAndMessaging/type.HICON.html) [handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902967/what-is-a-windows-handle):

```rust
pub type HICON = isize;
```

P.S. This is how TAO [check visibility](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tao/blob/dev/src/platform_impl/windows/window.rs#L607-L609) of a window on Windows.

P.P.S. Same place has ~[7 ways](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tao/blob/dev/src/platform_impl/windows/window.rs#L352-L408) to get your windows hardware id in `HWND` and other formats.

Comment: @IInspectable added more details to the answer to address how to display an icon per window using Tauri.

Comment: That's not useful. The OP needs the *visual representation* of the icon image identified by an `HICON` and have it serialized in a format that can be displayed in HTML. Conflating the `windows` and `windows-sys` crates isn't helpful either. (And no, an `HICON` isn't a pointer.)

Comment: Added `HICON` to `PNG` conversion.

Comment: This doesn't work for icons that have a mask and likely drops the alpha channel from 32bpp icons.

Comment: @IInspectable This is true, but at least it's something :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@DeveloperMindset.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23186351/developermindset-com) for their crucial help.

I modified it a bit to make it work with winapi since i wasnt able to make it work with window.rs, and change it in a way that extracts the icon from the exe path.

```
unsafe fn icon_to_rgba_image(icon: HICON, hwnd: HWND) -> String {
    let bitmap_size = i32::try_from(mem::size_of::<BITMAP>()).unwrap();
    let biheader_size = u32::try_from(mem::size_of::<BITMAPINFOHEADER>()).unwrap();

    let mut info = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    GetIconInfo(icon, info.as_mut_ptr());
    let info = info.assume_init_ref();
    DeleteObject(info.hbmMask as *mut c_void);

    let mut bitmap: MaybeUninit<BITMAP> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
    let result = GetObjectW(
        info.hbmColor as *mut c_void,
        bitmap_size,
        bitmap.as_mut_ptr().cast(),
    );

    if result != bitmap_size {
        return "".to_string();
    }

    let bitmap = bitmap.assume_init_ref();

    let width = u32::try_from(bitmap.bmWidth).unwrap();
    let height = u32::try_from(bitmap.bmHeight).unwrap();
    let w = usize::try_from(bitmap.bmWidth).unwrap();
    let h = usize::try_from(bitmap.bmHeight).unwrap();

    let buf_size = w
        .checked_mul(h)
        .and_then(|size| size.checked_mul(4))
        .unwrap();
    let mut buf: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(buf_size);

    let dc = GetDC(hwnd);

    let mut bitmap_info = BITMAPINFOHEADER {
        biSize: biheader_size,
        biWidth: bitmap.bmWidth,
        biHeight: -bitmap.bmHeight,
        biPlanes: 1,
        biBitCount: 32,
        biCompression: 0,
        biSizeImage: 0,
        biXPelsPerMeter: 0,
        biYPelsPerMeter: 0,
        biClrUsed: 0,
        biClrImportant: 0,
    };
    GetDIBits(
        dc,
        info.hbmColor,
        0,
        height,
        buf.as_mut_ptr().cast(),
        addr_of_mut!(bitmap_info).cast(),
        DIB_RGB_COLORS,
    );

    buf.set_len(buf.capacity());

    let result = ReleaseDC(hwnd, dc);
    assert!(result == 1);
    DeleteObject(info.hbmColor as *mut c_void);

    for chunk in buf.chunks_exact_mut(4) {
        let [b, _, r, _] = chunk else { unreachable!() };
        mem::swap(b, r);
    }

    let img = RgbaImage::from_vec(width, height, buf).unwrap();

    let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    img.write_to(&mut Cursor::new(&mut data), image::ImageOutputFormat::Png)
        .unwrap();

    general_purpose::STANDARD.encode(&data)
}
```