# Converting arraybuffer to string : Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, data-conversion, arraybuffer

This is my code.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET',window.location.href, true);
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
xhr.onload = function(event) {
 debugger;
 console.log(" coverting array buffer to string "); 
 alert(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(this.response)));
};
xhr.send();
```

That request is being made to a PDF URL which is around 3 MB in size. I have read a few threads with same error, *Maximum call stack size exceeded*, telling me that there must be some recursive call but I do not see any recursive call here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this request to the very same page? Using GET on `window.location.href`?

Comment: @skobaljic Yes.For example, the current page is http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~lok/3101/lectures/02-corejava.pdf

Comment: If you call same page with same script included, why do you wonder there is too much recursion? Try calling other page with no script. Or if you call via xhr, than do not output the script again, or add parameter to distinct the call.

Comment: @skobaljic this script wont execute in load function. I am just reading the pdf page data.

Comment: Have you tried to load other page, other pdf?

Comment: @skobaljic Well, this code is inside extension. When people click an option this code gets execute. If the page is we pure html page, I am using jquery to get body text , where as for pdf url's I can use jquery body text. So reading the contents as arraybuffer and trying to parse it to a string. That is where I am getting this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117594/discussion-between-ss--and-skobaljic).

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem and I finally used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9458996/535203):

```js
function _arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
    var binary = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
    var len = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
    }
    return window.btoa( binary );
}
```

Comment: could use `reduce` instead, but this seems to be what is necessary

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. works like a charm

Answer (score 14):

The error is caused by a limitation in the number of function arguments. See ["RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22123769/rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-why)

Instead of `String.fromCharCode.apply()`, use e. g. a `TextEncoder`. See [Uint8Array to string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936984/uint8array-to-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Hi. How do you use the `TextEncoder` in my case? I have this `var base64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(blob)));`

Comment: I opened a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123222/converting-array-buffer-to-string-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

Comment: For a binary string `TextEncoder` is useless, it does not support `Latin1` (it uses `Windows−1252`), you will get the broken result. `(new TextDecoder("ISO-8859-1").decode(new Uint8Array([148]))).charCodeAt(0);` // 8221, should be 148

Answer (score 6):

```
this.response.arrayBuffer()
              .then((buf) => {
                const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(buf);
                const data = uint8Array.reduce((acc, i) => acc += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [i]), '');
                return data;
              })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Thank you so much Anthony O, you saved my 10 days work.
small modification in my scenario is:

Angular 7 :

/** Convert Uint8Array to string */

    private static arrayBufferToBase64( buffer: Uint8Array ) {
        var binary = '';
        var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
        var len = bytes.byteLength;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
        }
        return  binary;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more optimized variant would be to utilize the available stack size instead of converting each character separately.

```
var text = '';
for(var i = 0; i < Math.ceil(bytes.length / 32768.0); i++) {
  text += String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bytes.slice(i * 32768, Math.min((i+1) * 32768, bytes.length)))
}
```