# Converting an encoded JPEG image to Uint8Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, socket.io, jpeg

I have a python server that sends a frame of RGB data to my JS script via a websocket. The frame is encoded using simplejpeg python package.
The code looks like this:

```
jpeg_frame = simplejpeg.encode_jpeg(image=color_frame, quality=85,colorspace='RGB', colorsubsampling='444', fastdct=True)
```

jpeg_frame is passed to the websocket and sent to the JS script.

On the JS side however, I would like to decompress the image and have it in the form of a Uint8Array so that I can work with the data. The image does not have to be viewed.

The data recieved is in the form of ArrayBuffer.

This is what I have so far.

```
socketio.on('colorFrame',(data)=>{
    var mime = 'image/jpeg';
    var a = new Uint8Array(data);
    var nb = a.length;
    if (nb < 4)
        return null;
    var binary = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < nb; i++)
        binary += String.fromCharCode(a[i]);
    var base64 = window.btoa(binary);
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'data:' + mime + ';base64,' + base64;
    
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0)

    image.onload = function(){
        var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0,0, 960, 540);
        console.log(image_data);
    };
});
```

So far I could not yet figure out how I can decompress the image. I dont mind the inaccuracy of the lossy compression, I just want the image back to its original resolution and be able to convert it to a Uint8Array.

What is the simplest way to get JPEG decoding working in a JS scrip?

Comment: You might want to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-arraybuffer instead of rolling your own decoding...

Comment: But yep, you're on the right track. Once you have a loaded `Image`, you can use a canvas 2D context to paint it, then `getImageData` to work with the pixels.

Comment: You will also want to attach to the `image.onload` event, as even with data uri the image is not ready until onload is fired.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have updated the answer to include the new lines of code. When I console log the image data, all the pixels are 0.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent article ["Decoding a PNG Image in JavaScript"](https://www.mwguy.com/decoding-a-png-image-in-javascript/) that answers the literal question. It's a non-trivial answer. (Note: I am not the author of the article)

## However

Based on your code, it looks like you might not care about actually decoding the Image yourself. If you just want to display it, take a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950865/javascript-render-png-stored-as-uint8array-onto-canvas-element-without-data-uri)