# "Aw, Snap" when data uri is too large

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, data-uri

I'm writing a chrome extension which does the following:

1. Downloads a file from a website to memory using `XMLHttpRequest`
2. Adds additional data to the file and then base64 encodes the result to the variable `total_encoded_data`
3. Offers the data to the user using `<a href=data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,' + total_encoded_data+' download='file.bin'>Click to Download</a>`. Where `total_encoded_data` is added to href using jQuery.

I have found, through a manual binary search, that if the size of `total_encoded_data` is greater than 2097100 characters, then I will get an Aw, Snap message when I click the link. If the size is smaller, then I can download as expected.

In addition to testing the filesize, I also used `atoi` to ensure that the base64 encoding is valid, and it operates without error.

The Aw, Snap messages don't produce any crash reports in `chrome://crashes` nor any unexpected output in the `chrome_debug.log`

How do I avoid an Aw, Snap message when serving a data uri where the base64 encoded string length is greater than 2097100?

Comment: perhaps this trivia tidbit might be of some use in designing a workaround strategy - 
`2097100 + 52`  = `8^7` aka `2^21`. As for even closer to that number,  `2097100 + 1`  neatly factors into `1399 x 1499`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It's a [known chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69227).  The recommended workaround is to use a [blob URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.URL.createObjectURL).  Also see [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/how-can-i-get-a-blob-from-a-base64-encoded-string).

Comment: 3.5 years later... still not fixed. God damn it, Chrome.

Comment: Almost 7 years later... and solved the same old issue with the blob url trick!

Comment: If anybody is wondering, the maximum size is based on 2MB in bytes... 2 * 1024 * 1024 bytes.

Comment: Honestly guys this is ridiculous, it's almost 2018 and still there... I know why I dumped Apple... Unfortunately I have lots of clients with iPhones *raises fist* :)

Comment: This answer just helped me out so much. Thank you @rhashimoto !

Comment: 2020 and we're still waiting!

Comment: 2022 still not solved

Comment: 2023... wen :((((

Comment: Does anyone know why the workaround wouldn't work? I got a little over 2MB image that still freezes the tab when converted to blob url?