# Offer a token protected file from flask using angular

Tags: angularjs, download, flask, token, flask-security

- I have a file, served with flask, protected with token based
  authentication.
- I want to offer a download to it from an angular app
- the token is stored in the angular session and put into the header of each $http.get or post

But when I just place a link to the flask path, the token is not added in the request header since it is no angular $http.get() but just an ordinary anchor I cannot do this (right?).

I dont want to pass the token in the url as query string parameter.
How do I offer the dowload to the user? Should I first $http.get() it into angular and then tunnel it through as a file download?

Token storage after login:

```
$window.sessionStorage.token = results.response.user.authentication_token;
```

It is injected in each $http get or post:

```
config.headers['Authentication-Token'] = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
```

Flask (with flask-security) part:

```
@app.route("/download", methods=['GET'])
@auth_token_required
def download():
    response = make_response(open('filename.ext').read())
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=download.ext"
    return response
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Take a look at the solution [here](http://blog.techdev.de/an-angularjs-directive-to-download-pdf-files/). Only works with HTML5 though.

Comment: Thanks! that is a nice trick, I will write the answer soon

Answer (score 0):

First you get the data via $http.get()

Then there are two approaches I found:

1. Insert the data as base64 encoded data inside the href attribute
2. Insert the data as javascript blob and place a blob link in the
       href    attribute

The first method was suggested by the [article](http://blog.techdev.de/an-angularjs-directive-to-download-pdf-files/) recommended by @Christian in the comments. 
I implemented it and you can find the code below. However the method made Chrome crash for larger files (csv files in this case), apparently this is [a limitation of chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761927/aw-snap-when-data-uri-is-too-large).
So I would recommend method 2.

### Method 2

Angular (for csv files in this case, change the type: 'text/csv' accordingly for other files:

```
$http.get('/downloadpath').
    success(function(downloadresult){
        fileData = new Blob([downloadresult], { type: 'text/csv' }); 
        fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(fileData);
        $scope.download_href = fileUrl;
    });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="{{download_href}}" download="filename.ext">download</a>
```

Flask:

```
@app.route("/downloadpath", methods=['GET'])
@auth_token_required
def download():
    response = open('filename.ext','br').read()
    return response
```

And just to be complete, here is method 1:

### Method 1

```
 $http.get('/downloadpath').
    success(function(downloadresult){
        $scope.download_href = downloadresult;
    });
```

And for the html the same:

```
<a href="{{download_href}}" download="filename.ext">download</a>
```

Flask (example for csv file, change the 'data:text/csv' if you have another file):

```
@app.route("/downloadpath", methods=['GET'])
@auth_token_required
def download():
    encoded = base64.b64encode(open('export.csv','br').read())
    response = 'data:text/csv;base64,{}'.format(str(encoded, encoding='utf-8'))
    return response
```

### Angular requirement for both methods

You need to whitelist the blob protocol for method 2 and the data protocol for method 1:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config( [
    '$compileProvider',
    function( $compileProvider )
    {   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|data|blob):/);
    }
]);
```