# How to export large amount of json data to CSV using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried this below code to export but it's giving error('failed - network error') in Chrome Browser if json data size is too large. For small size of data it's working fine.

```
<script>
var items = [
    {university: 'A',college: 'X',state: 'J'},
    {university: 'B',college: 'Y',state: 'K'},
    {university: 'C',college: 'Z',state: 'L'}
];

// Convert Object to JSON
var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);
var array = typeof jsonObject != 'object' ? JSON.parse(jsonObject) : jsonObject;
var csv = '';
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var line = '';
    for (var index in array[i]) {
    if (line != '') line += ','
        line += array[i][index];
    }
    csv += line + '\r\n';
}
var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
data = encodeURI(uri);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = data;
link.style = "visibility:hidden";
link.download = "xyz.csv";
link.click();
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the size of your JSON file?

Comment: try exporting in chunks rather than as a whole.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761927/aw-snap-when-data-uri-is-too-large | Also found this fiddle which uses `Blob` for generating a csv: http://jsfiddle.net/5C98A/9/

Comment: `Internal Server Error` without interacting with the server? I'm intrigued. Can you provide a screenshot of the error?

Comment: What piyin said. Are you missing out some detail here? Some JS in the browser can't cause a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for large amount of data

```
var items = [{
    university: 'A',
    college: 'X',
    state: 'J'
  },
  {
    university: 'B',
    college: 'Y',
    state: 'K'
  },
  {
    university: 'C',
    college: 'Z',
    state: 'L'
  }
];

// Convert Object to JSON
var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(items);
var array = typeof jsonObject != 'object' ? JSON.parse(jsonObject) : jsonObject;
var csv = '';
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var line = '';
  for (var index in array[i]) {
    if (line != '') line += ','
    line += array[i][index];
  }
  csv += line + '\r\n';
}
csvData = new Blob([csv], {
  type: "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF"
});
var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = csvUrl;
a.setAttribute("download", fileName + ".csv");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```