# Download file using javascript or jquery without calling webapi

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

Is it possible to simulate browser download (Save As..) using javascript or jquery without calling WebApi? I'm thinking of redirecting the page to the Service Proxy's Url?

Comment: It would be a major security issue

Comment: Do you mean you want to download a file generated via js? If that's the case than this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you for your reply :) yeah, i thought so too, there would be a security issue.

Comment: @mot Would there be an issue if the file is too big? let's say the file is around 1GB. Thank you! :D

Comment: @chary I'm not sure about that, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082286/getting-max-data-uri-size-in-javascript but I didn't find it too conclusive. Go ahead and check for us :)