# Angular Requesting a csv file download url, and force download

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, download

How to trigger a csv file download from within Angular on a button click?

The backend is the php route.

I tried solutions which adds an anchor tag dynamically and appends to it's href attribute, the csv file content after getting from the http request. But it didn't work for me... also as we are appending the csc content to the href attribute, i was concerned about the length of the href for how much content it allows.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with the existing answers, i tried the below and its worked.

Using angular 1.5.9

I made it working like this by setting the window.location to the csv file download url. Tested and its working with the latest version of Chrome and IE11.

Angular

```
   $scope.downloadStats = function downloadStats{
        var csvFileRoute = '/stats/download';
        $window.location = url;
    }
```

html

```
<a target="_self" ng-click="downloadStats()"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> CSV</a>
```

In php set the below headers for the response:

```
$headers = [
    'content-type'              => 'text/cvs',
    'Content-Disposition'       => 'attachment; filename="export.csv"',
    'Cache-control'             => 'private, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
    'Content-transfer-encoding' => 'binary',
    'Expires' => '0',
    'Pragma' => 'public',
];
```

Comment: `text/cvs` or `text/csv`?