# More than 3000 items exporting to excel issue in chrome

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

i am trying to export the records to the excel. Here i have more than 3000 records. When i have below 3000 records it was exporting and saving. But if i have more than 3000 records i am facing the issue. while saving Failed - network error is coming.

Used below code to export the records to excel.

```
function SaveContents(element, filename) {
if (window.Blob && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    var blob = new Blob([element], {
        type: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel'
    });
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename + '.xls');
} else {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF' + encodeURIComponent(element);
    a.download = filename + ".xls";
    a.click();
}}
```

Please give a solution to this.

Comment: Check the value of `blob.size`. Could possibly be the blob size exceeding the max allowed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307789/is-there-any-limitation-on-javascript-max-blob-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you should be doing it any more. Quite a while ago, two things were added:

- `download` attribute for `<a>` that initiates download of the target. Example:

  ```
  <a href="myfile.png" download="image.png">Download image</a>
  ```
- `URL.createObjectURL` which converts blob to a virtual URL that can be treated as a file on the internet, try this for example:

  ```
  // convert letters to bytes
  const letters = new Uint8Array([..."Hello world"].map((x)=>x.charCodeAt(0)));
  const blob = new Blob([letters], {type:"text/plain"});
  // Try to open the result in new tab
  console.log(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  // remember to clear the URL later using URL.revokeObjectURL
  ```

So replace the part of your code that sets the URL like this:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
var blob = new Blob([element], {
    type: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel'
});
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.download = filename + ".xls";
a.click();
// lazy cleanup, note that this renders the link invalid
setTimeout(()=>{URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);}, 500);
```