# Is there a size limit on MediaRecorder API record?

Tags: javascript, blob, web-mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I'm using [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) to record a video, the video is suppose to run for a few hours, It is eventually around 400MB in size, I want to know if there's a predefined limit on how much data can the browser store using the API.

I couldn't find it in MDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking in [w3c](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-record/) standard and [chromium's source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/modules/mediarecorder/MediaRecorder.cpp).

And as it turns out, There is no standard for limiting records, every browser has its own implementation.
Chrome's (chromium) limit seems to be only as the limit of its Blob's sizes that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307789/is-there-any-limitation-on-javascript-max-blob-size).

Answer (score 2):

Just faced similar issue, and this is my solution.

Firstly you set up a timer, then call MediaRecorder.requestData() frequently, finally check your data size.

```js
let recordedBlobs = [];
let recordedBlobSize = 0;
let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
mediaRecorder.onstop = handleStop;
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
mediaRecorder.start();
setInterval(onTimerUpdate, 10000)

function onTimerUpdate() {
    mediaRecorder.requestData()
}

function handleDataAvailable(event) {
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        recordedBlobs.push(event.data);
        recordedBlobSize += event.data.size
        // check your size here
    }
}
```