# Cant use base64 image inside img tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, base64

Node js

```
unirest.get("MYROUTE")
.header("X-Mashape-Key", "MYKEY")
.end(function (result) {
  console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
  if(result.status==200) {
    var buffer = (new Buffer(result.body.toString()));
    res.end(buffer.toString("base64")); // output content as response body
    //res.end('data:image/jpg;base64,'+result.body)
  }
});
```

Returns (I erased a lot, but its base64)

```
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
```

With angular I get `res.data` which is the base64, I try to use it inside a img tag but the image is not working?

How do I use this base64 to display images?

Comment: You need to format it as a [data-uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML)

Comment: How are you setting the response to img tag?

Comment: TemplateData.getData().then(function(res) {
      console.log(res.data);
      $('body').html('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + res.data + '" />');
    }, function(status) {
      console.log(status);
    })

Comment: Just a quick thought - how large is the image? Is it falling foul of this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695151/data-protocol-url-size-limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.  The `img` tag should look something like this:

```
<div>
    <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>
```

The base64 you pasted into your question does look correct; however, ensure that the client is receiving the proper payload and HTML encoding isn't stripping and/or converting characters.

Comment: Thanks for the response I am logging the `res.data` and it looks fine.