# React:write to json file or export/download [no server]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-io, blob

I got really confused with file I/O in JS/TS. most examples I see works with DOM and has browser-based solutions.

Also, I did not understand how to make `fs` work, it seems to need a webpack config, where I use CRA and do not want to eject.

in a React component I want to fetch some data from a server then save them as a JSON file in the project folder (the same path, root, public folder, no matter) or directly download (no button needed).

```
//data type just in case
inteface IAllData{ name:string; allData:IData[];}
```

so after fetching some data want to save them to `name.json`

```
public componentDidMount(){
   this.fetchData().then(()=>this.saveData())
}

public async fetchData(){/* sets data in state*/}

public saveData(){
    const {myData}=this.state;
    const fileName=myData.name;
    const json=JSON.stringify(myData);
    const blob=new Blob([json],{type:'application/json'})
    /* How to write/download this blob as a file? */
}
```

here trying `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'export.json');` did not work

**note:** I know it has security risks, it is not for production. save the file in the project folder is preferred but a download is totally ok.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had a blob containing data and I had found a solution on stackoverflow and manipulated a bit, and succeded to download as a xlsx file. I am adding my code below, it might help you, too.

```
const blob =  await res.blob(); // blob just as yours
const href = await URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = href;
link.download = "file.xlsx";
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

EDIT: You can use the function below, but be sure to switch out `fileName` and `myData` from `this.state` to something that will work in your application.

```
const downloadFile = () => {
  const { myData } = this.state; // I am assuming that "this.state.myData"
                                 // is an object and I wrote it to file as
                                 // json

  // create file in browser
  const fileName = "my-file";
  const json = JSON.stringify(myData, null, 2);
  const blob = new Blob([json], { type: "application/json" });
  const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  // create "a" HTLM element with href to file
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = href;
  link.download = fileName + ".json";
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();

  // clean up "a" element & remove ObjectURL
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
}
```

More documentation for [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) is available on MDN. It's critical to release the object with [`URL.revokeObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) to prevent a memory leak. In the function above, since we've already downloaded the file, we can immediately revoke the object.

> Each time you call createObjectURL(), a new object URL is created, even if you've already created one for the same object. Each of these must be released by calling URL.revokeObjectURL() when you no longer need them.

> Browsers will release object URLs automatically when the document is unloaded; however, for optimal performance and memory usage, if there are safe times when you can explicitly unload them, you should do so.

Answer (score 18):

For the ones like me here that are looking for an easier solution when you already have your JSON as a variable:

```
         <button
            href={`data:text/json;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(
              JSON.stringify(YOURJSON)
            )}`}
            download="filename.json"
          >
            {`Download Json`}
          </button>
```

Comment: this code didn't work for me until I changed <button> to <a>

Comment: @user2584621's solution worked for me. And is there any limitation for the data length? For me, it's going to be a huge file.

Comment: There is some information on data uri limits here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695151/data-protocol-url-size-limitations

Answer (score 3):

```
<button
  type="button"
  href={`data:text/json;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(
   JSON.stringify(YOURJSON)
  )}`}
  download="filename.json"
  >
 {`Download Json`}
 </button>
```

if you are using the Loic V method just ad the type for the button on the button element and should work just fine.