# Converting HTML to base64 is not encoding certain characters correctly

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, base64

I am trying to convert an HTML string to base64 which I will then display in an iframe but I am running into some issues. When I encode the string as base64 and view it as a data URI, it is display non-breaking spaces as 'Â', and other characters such as apostrophes and dashes are displayed as random ASCII characters.

This is how I am converting the string to base64:

```
var blob = new Blob([message], {
    type: contentType
});
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
     let result = e.target.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Any ideas on how to prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: But why are you converting HTML to base64 in the first place?

Comment: @JeremyThille I need to be able to display it in an iframe

Comment: hence my question. You want to display HTML in an iframe... why convert it to base64? Iframes are meant to display HTML. Sounds like a XY problem to me

Comment: @JeremyThille Maybe I am confused about how an iframe works but how would I go about putting a large HTML string in one? I am converting it to a base64 data URI and setting that to the source of the iframe right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to do what you're doing.  Data URIs are almost always the wrong choice.  Base-64 encoding adds 33% overhead of size and wastes CPU.  Data URIs are [subjected to some strict size limits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755526/362536).

Use a Blob/Object URL instead.

```
iframe.src = URL.createBlobURL(blob);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

As to your UTF-8 encoding problem, the issue is likely in your file itself, in that if you're not serving from a server which sets the character set in the headers, it needs to be in the file:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

There's no server here, so you need to declare it in the file.