# Display img from bytes generated by python's pillow module

Tags: javascript, python, python-imaging-library

I read an jpg image with python using [pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) module:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('./test.jpg')
bytes = img.tobytes()
```

If I print `bytes` I get something like this:

```py
print(f'{bytes}')
# b'\xbe\xb0i\xb1\xa4^\xb1\xaad\xab\xa7`\xc2\xc0v\x96\x91Oj_2\xb7...
```

I send then this 'bytes string' to my `js` to display it:

```js
var b64imgData = btoa(bytes); // bytes is the 'bytes string' show upper
var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + b64imgData;

$('#imgCtn').append(img);
```

Sadly the final image source doesn't seem to be valid because I get the invalid image icon instead of my image `test.jpg`.

Has someone an idea where the issue is ?

---

**EDIT 1:**

As it is mentionned by [@cubrr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/996081/cubrr) don't use `img.tobytes()` method for jpg files. So for the python code please use this one:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('./test.jpg')
imageBytes = io.BytesIO()
img.save(imageBytes, format='JPEG')
bytes = imageBytes.getvalue()
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this since, from the comments OP has made, there appear to be many distinct issues here.

Comment: @AMC Well I understand but in my opinion I will not be the only one to search to achieve this type of feature and there are not a lot of questions that raise it on SO.

Comment: In that case it might be better to edit your post to accurately reflect what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation of Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes):

> `Image.tobytes(encoder_name='raw', *args)`
>
> ...
>
> **Warning: This method returns the raw image data from the internal storage. For compressed image data (e.g. PNG, JPEG) use save(), with a BytesIO parameter for in-memory data.**

So try using `save` to get the JPG bytes instead of the raw internal image data:

```
img = Image.open('./test.jpg')
imageBytes = io.BytesIO()
img.save(imageBytes, format='JPEG')
bytes = imageBytes.getvalue()
```

If if still does not work, please elaborate on what you mean by "send this bytes string to my js". How are you sending and receiving it (code please)?

Comment: Ok Thanks but where does I have to specify my image name ? I use a websockets service to send it to my `js`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Does it not work if you just send the `bytes` from my example just like you send the `bytes` from your own example?

Comment: I updated my example to include your `Image.open` if that helps

Comment: Ok so it does'nt display the image too. When I look to my DOM, I see that the image has a `src` attribute like that `src="data:image/jpg;base64,YidceGZmXHhkOFx4ZmZ..."`

Comment: That contains `\xff\xd8\xff` which is the start of JPG's header so appears alright. How large is your image? Data URLs do have [browser specific size limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695151/data-protocol-url-size-limitations). If you don't specifically need to transfer that image over a websocket, you could add an endpoint in your server that generates whatever image you need to generate, and set the URL of that endpoint as the `src`.

Comment: It's a really little picture like `30x20` px so I don't think that is the problem. Moreover `format='JPG'` don't seems to be valid (I got an error) and after research I have seen that `JPG` is not the right format but `JPEG` is.