# How to load embedded object in webbrowser control of a userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to load a .gif image in the webbrowser control of a userform. I can import the .gif from a normal path as seen in the Code1, but I want to navigate to embedded .gif which is "object 6". How do I do it? I tried Code2, but could not. Thank you

**Code1:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "C:\Pictures\Splash.gif"

End Sub
```

Code2

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate2 OLEObjects("Object 6")

End Sub
```

Comment: If your image is static you can easily do it with the picture tool but I'm guessing your gif is animated. That makes it a lot more difficult and to be honest I'm not sure it can actually be done with the web browser tool. Please prove me wrong someone cause I would actually like to know if it's possible as well.

Comment: @Simon Hi Simon, yes my gif is animated and that is why I cannot use picture tool. Yes, it can be done with the web browser tool but from the normal folder path. What I want to achieve is to load the embedded gif in the workbook. Thanks

Comment: I know it can be done by loading a path, I was referring to loading it from within a sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your gif is not too large you could try converting it to a data uri:

https://ezgif.com/image-to-datauri

Store the converted image as text in a worksheet cell, then you can do something like this:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    With Me.WebBrowser1
        .Navigate "about:blank"
        While .ReadyState <> 4 Or .Busy: DoEvents: Wend
        .Document.body.innerhtml = Sheet4.Range("A1").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Tested and works for me.

Some info on datauri limits: [Data protocol URL size limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695151/data-protocol-url-size-limitations)

Max you can store in a cell is 32k characters, but you could split a larger string over multiple cells.

Comment: Cheers for the @ (though it didn't work lol). I had a thought to maybe insert a gif into the sheet as a picture (as normal). Then when the form loads it could export that gif to maybe the VBA Environ or something then the webbrowser can load the gif from there. Is it possible to export a moving image out of excel? I know static images can be done through loading it into a chart then exporting but that doesn't work for gifs.

Comment: "it didn't work lol"  - works fine for me; do you care to try to get it working for you?

Comment: Sorry I meant your @ didn't notify me. I managed to get your way working after I realised the code I got was more than 32k characters. What about the rest of my comment though? Is there a way to do that? You're the man of all knowledge lol

Comment: I've never tried it that way but the image needs to be a file somewhere accessible to the HTML hosted in the web browser control: outside of a regular file (or hosting it somewhere) I don't know how you'd make that work.

Comment: @Tim Williams Works perfect! Thanks have a good time! :)