# Transparent PNG can't be displayed but is downloadable

Tags: html, image, data-uri

I'm currently trying to display PNGs with react-three-fiber but when I set a texture with a transparent background it doesn't show.
I've tried many things but noticed that if I take the base64 of the image and load it into a `img` html element, it doesn't display either, otherwise, if I put it as an href for an `a` element, I can download it with no issue.

Here is a live exemple where you can download the file but not load it into an img:
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-elion-tznyx?file=/index.html
You may open the sample in a separated tab as codesandbox is preventing file download from the reduced window.

If anyone ever experienced this, maybe something in the base64 is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing this same demo in Safari, it will work correctly. In Firefox and Chrome it does not. Data URIs are best used for small images — they add a ~30% size penalty to the data they store, and a significant amount of extra processing is required to display them. Browsers including Chrome impose limits on the supported length of Data URIs for this reason, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755526/1314762 for details on those limits.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know! Unfortunatly, safari is the only browser our app wouldn't support for now 