# Base64 pdf with size > 3MB not loading with iframe

Tags: php, google-chrome, iframe, base64

Base64 PDF iframe is not displaying on Chrome.

PHP/HTML:

```
<?php
    $pdf = base64_encode(file_get_contents('https://freetestdata.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Free_Test_Data_10.5MB_PDF.pdf'));
    echo '<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,' . $pdf . '></iframe>';
?>
```

I tried `<embed>`, specifying `width` and `height`, and `type="application/pdf"` but it's not working.

The file size is > 10MB I tried with 3MB file not working.

It only worked with 39kb pdf.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your HTML. It should be: `echo '<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,' . $pdf . '"></iframe>';`. Note the addition of the double quote. If your code really looks like this, why don't you just put the URL of the PDF in the SRC attribute of the IFRAME?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it's a typo while copying the code but it's not the issue. I don't want to put the URL because I don't want to give the users direct access to the PDF file.

Comment: I tested your code, after correcting the typo, and it worked for me. However, I agree with KJ that there might be a limit on [the size of the data URL that a browser will accept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695151/data-protocol-url-size-limitations). I'm using Firefox on Windows 11. I'll provide an answer with an alternative way to download the PDF which doesn't involve this limitation.

Answer (score -1):

To circumvent the data URL length limit you can create a PHP script on your server that will download the file for you:

```
<?php

header('Content-type:application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition:inline;filename="downloaded.pdf"');
readfile('https://freetestdata.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Free_Test_Data_10.5MB_PDF.pdf');
```

See: [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile). The headers are needed to tell the browser it's a PDF and what the file name is.

Now suppose you call this PHP script "download_pdf.php" you can use it like this:

```
<?php

echo '<iframe src="download_pdf.php"></iframe>';
```

Now you're not saying anything about this, but if you want to be able to download more than one PDF you could work with an URL argument, like this:

```
<?php

echo '<iframe src="download_pdf.php?fileId=3"></iframe>';
```

and then you need to modify the script like this:

```
<?php

switch (intval($_GET['fileId'] ?? 0)) {
   case 0 : $url = 'https://example.com/404_error.pdf';
            break;
   case 1 : $url = '.....';
            break;
   case 2 : $url = '.....';
            break;
   case 3 : $url = 'https://freetestdata.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Free_Test_Data_10.5MB_PDF.pdf';
            break;
   case 4 : $url = '.....';
            break;
}

header('Content-type:application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition:inline;filename="downloaded.pdf"');
readfile($url);
```

This is just an example. The URL could come from an array, or even from a database table.