# When using document.location.href to save client-side data, how can I suggest a filename to the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to export an HTML5 canvas as a PNG file, so that it is stored on the user's computer.

The following snippet saves the image correctly.

```
document.location.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
```

However using Chrome on Mac OS X, it always is saved as "download". In Safari it is called "Unknown". Firefox gives it a gobbledygook name.

Can I suggest to the browser a name to use, such as "exportedImage.png"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)

Comment: I once came across a tip of sending the `data:` to a server, which in turn sends the data back with some appropriate headers. I've not yet tried it though, but perhaps it's worth a shot.

Comment: location object belongs to window, not document, btw

Comment: @user759588: It works with both.

Comment: @pimvdb, document.location is non-standard quirk from dark 199x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently a topic of discussion in browser bug lists and [a W3C mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/uri/2010Feb/0058.html).  I can't find any evidence that any browser supports the idea of a filename parameter in a "data:" URL, though it is clear that the spec supports the idea of parameters in general.

Also see [this older SO question, which is essentially the same as this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)