# How to give file name at base 64 images

Tags: html, image, base64

I have following code which use image of base64, when i right click on ti and save it, it tried to save as download.gif. how can i give the name of file to download instead of having name as download.gif?

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp
V0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7" 
width="16" height="14" alt="embedded folder icon">
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)

Answer (score 14):

You can use link wrap with `download` attribute.

```
<a href="data:image/gif;base64,R0l...QA7" download="some_name.gif">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0l...QA7" width="16" height="14" alt="embedded folder icon"/>
</a>
```

Right click - save object as - this get you name in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot.  The [data URI spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) does not allow for specification of a file name.