# How to force the filename extension of a downloaded gzipped data URI?

Tags: html, google-chrome, gzip, filenames, data-uri

I have a GZipped JavaScript file which I am encoding with a data:URI.

For example:

```
<a href="data:application/x-gzip;base64,FOO">My Javascript File</a>
```

When the user right-clicks and saves this file (in Chrome) I would like the resulting file's name to be `download.js.gz`. This way when the user double clicks this file (in Mac OS X), it gets decompressed and renamed correctly to `download.js`, and they can view the contents easily.

The problem is that when I use the content type `text/javascript` (or `application/x-javascript`), the file gets saved as `download.js`. And when I use the content type `application/x-gzip`, the file gets saved as `download.gz`.

Is there any way to get the file to be saved as `.js.gz`?

Here's a working example of both links: http://jsfiddle.net/xYm8w/3/

The file must be a data uri and not a link to an actual file. I tried changing the text between the `<a>` tags, but it doesn't affect anything at all.

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this in browsers besides Chrome. Therefore, the best option I could think of is to inform the user to save the file normally (so that it automatically inserts the proper extension based on the content type), and then having them go into finder and renaming the file to append the '.gz' extension.

On Chrome, though, you can use the `download` attribute of the `<a>` tag (which I found out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6943481/35690)). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pYpqW/

Comment: Correct. According to the specs (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397 ), there is no way of specifying the filename. A data url is to be considered a data stream - not a file.