# Download a file by changing window.location w/ Safari

Tags: javascript, url, safari

I have an offline html file that generates and saves a CSV by setting window.location to

```
data:text/csv;base64,Intfa2V5fSIsInt...
```

However, in Safari this just brings up the CSV in the browser.

Setting the url to:

```
data:application/csv;base64,Intfa2V5fSIsInt...
```

forces Safari to download the file - but it gets a generic file name of just 'Unknown-3'.  Is there a way to specify the file name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a warning:`application/csv` isn't a [valid MIME type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html), so the fact that it "works" for you in this case is purely an implementation quirk that could very well change in the future.  (For example, Safari *displays* `application/octet-stream`, which I'd expect to download.)

HTML5 does have a [new `<a download="file.name">` attribute](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download).  This forces the browser to download the file to disk; it uses the attribute's value as the default file name.  It does work in conjunction with a data URI or a [blob](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers-bloburis) URI. ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pYpqW/))

However, it is currently only supported by Chrome (14+).  Safari 5.1 ignores the attribute.

---

A possible alternative is to use the [Filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), but that gives you a sandboxed folder to work with.  You can't—for example—save a file directly to the user's Documents folder.  Instead, you can write a file to the sandbox and then redirect to file on the new `filesystem` schema:

```
location.assign('filesystem:http://example.com/temporary/somefile.csv');
```

This should invoke the UA's download mechanism (with the right filename!), but I haven't tested this, so it is possible Safari will just display the file anyway.

Comment: The problem here is: seems safari doesn't support File System API as well....http://caniuse.com/#feat=filesystem

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) no. There is no way.

Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri) related question.