# create text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create text file (notepad type file) using javascript. My code is given below but it is not working plz. Suggest me any solution for creating text file.

```
var txt = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = txt.CreateTextFile("D:\\test.txt", true);// means file is store in my D drive.
s.WriteLine('Hello');
s.Close();   `
```

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436398/use-javascript-to-write-to-text-file.  JavaScript won't really do this to a client computer though.  What are you trying to accomplish with the text file?

Comment: Are you running that using Windows Scripting Host (since it looks like that is the target environment)? If not, what JavaScript environment are you using? Node.js? A web browser extension? A webpage?

Comment: Re-opened, the answer below shows that it can be done, the user has to click on a link and the file will be downloaded, the user can choose where to save it.

Comment: Actually my task is that to write something in textarea and when user click on save button then textarea text are save in text file but after some time when user want's to change  textarea content then he can change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try this:

```
(function () {
var textFile = null,
  makeTextFile = function (text) {
    var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});

    // If we are replacing a previously generated file we need to
    // manually revoke the object URL to avoid memory leaks.
    if (textFile !== null) {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
    }

    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

    return textFile;
  };


  var create = document.getElementById('create'),
    textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

  create.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
    link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
    link.style.display = 'block';
  }, false);
})();

<textarea id="textbox">Type something here</textarea> <button id="create">Create file</button> <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
```

Also you can show this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uselesscode/qm5ag/)

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet demonstrate create a text files using the jQuery and HTML5 file API. For the sake of simplicity, in this example I am using Bootstrap CSS framework for building the page.

```js
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
  if ('Blob' in window) {
    var fileName = prompt('Please enter file name to save', 'Untitled.txt');
    if (fileName) {
      var textToWrite = $('#exampleTextarea').val().replace(/n/g, 'rn');
      var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], { type: 'text/plain' });

      if ('msSaveOrOpenBlob' in navigator) {
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(textFileAsBlob, fileName);
      } else {
        var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.download = fileName;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = 'Download File';
        
        if ('webkitURL' in window) {
          // Chrome allows the link to be clicked without actually adding it to the DOM.
          downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        } else {
          // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM before it can be clicked.
          downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
          downloadLink.click(function(){
            document.body.removeChild(event.target);
          }); 
          
          downloadLink.style.display = 'none';
          document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        }
        downloadLink.click();
      }
    }
  } else {
    alert('Your browser does not support the HTML5 Blob.');
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript playground.">
    <title>HTML, CSS, JS Playground</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initialscale=1" name="viewport"> 
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(document ).ready(function() {
        //Put your java script here
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">     
        <h1>Reading and Creating Text Files Using the HTML5 File API and jQuery</h1>
        <div class="form-group">            
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnOpen">Open...</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnSave">Save</button>
        </div>      
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" accept=".txt,.csv,.xml" class="hidden">
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" id="exampleTextarea"></textarea>       
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[source](https://stacktips.com/tutorials/html5/reading-and-creating-text-files-using-jquery-and-html5-file-api)