# Write to text file with javascript on GoDaddy server

Tags: javascript

I have tried numerous different codes that I have found here along with the following code below I got from learn.microsoft.com. They all give me the same error though. The error I get is "ActiveXObject is not defined". Can someone please tell me how to fix this issue. How do I define the object or is this yet another problem that is related to my host, GoDaddy?!?!

This is for a Plesk/Windows server hosted by GoDaddy.

This is a link is to just one of the codes from stackoverflow that I have tried: [Use JavaScript to write to text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436398/use-javascript-to-write-to-text-file)

Microsoft Code

```
<script>
   var fso, tf;
   fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   tf = fso.CreateTextFile("G:\mysite\file.txt", true);
   // Write a line with a newline character.
   tf.WriteLine("Testing 1, 2, 3.") ;
   // Write three newline characters to the file.
   tf.WriteBlankLines(3) ;
   // Write a line.
   tf.Write ("This is a test.");
   tf.Close();
</script>
```

Comment: Why do I get downvoted just for asking a question?

Answer (score 3):

You can't write to a file on the server with client-side JavaScript (if clients could write arbitrary files on servers then Google's homepage would be vandalised every second).

The code you've found could write to the hard disk of the computer the "page" was loaded on, but only if the "page" was an HTA application and not a web page.

The standard way to send data to an HTTP server from JavaScript is to make an HTTP request. You can do this with an Ajax API like [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

You then need a server-side program (written in the language of your choice) that will process the request and write to the file (although due to race conditions, you are normally better off using a database than a flat file).