# How to set img src for images that are only downloadable?

Tags: php, html

How to set img src for images that are only downloadable?

I have created donwload.php for image downloading using [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473932/browser-html-force-download-of-image-from-src-dataimage-jpegbase64?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

I have set an access restriction on images, so images will be only accessible through download.php.

I want to use this image in img tag like this.

```
<img src="donwload.php?url=images/something.jpg" />
```

But this is not working. Please help me on this.

Comment: I guess you can't - if you change mimetype to application/octet-stream - browser don't know what format is the image and can't display it.

Comment: Have you set mime types in headers to "image/jpeg" ?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't really prevent anyone from right-clicking an image and selecting "Save Image As…". ;-)

Your problem is easily solvable though. Embed your images as usual and wrap those you want to be downloadable with `<a>` tags point to your `download.php` file:

```
<a href="download.php?url=images/something.jpg" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/something.jpg" />
</a>
```