# jQuery, captured Image download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using an ip camera.

For live stream:

```
<img id="ip-camera-frame" src="http://192.168.1.10/GetData.cgi?CH=1"></img>
```

I take a snapshot from camera with link "/GetImage.cgi?CH=0" and i can set "img" tag in modalbox.

This snapshot is OK, I want to download captured image but all download methots getting an new capture and download.

```
<div id="snapshot" class="modal-demo">
<div class="custom-modal-text">
    <img id="snapshot-frame" width="100%"></img >
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="save-snapshot">Download Snapshot</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to download captured image, this captured image in "<img id="snapshot-frame"></img>".  but this img src link at every refresh, get a new image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy image data from already loaded and displayed image.
as it describe here:

[Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

and download it like it described here:

[Browser/HTML Force download of image from src="data:image/jpeg;base64..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473932/browser-html-force-download-of-image-from-src-dataimage-jpegbase64)

so you should have something like:

```
document.getElementById('save-snapshot').addEventListener("click", function(e) {



var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
img.onload = function() {
var   canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    // guess the original format, maybe "image/jpg"
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    window.open(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));
};
img.src = document.getElementById("ip-camera-frame").src;

}, false);
```

Comment: Updated an answer. There maybe Cross-Origin security error (in previous solution), so the solution is to create a copy if image.