# linux www server for security file download (chmod)

Tags: php, file, privileges, chmod

I have problem with chmod on my server. For client I build security link for download file like:

> mydomain.com/download/123

It work ok, function download use file_get_content and header and it's works, but when I open link for example:

> mydomain.com/upload/somefolder/somefile.jpg

This file view too :(

what chmod I must set on folder upload to block link direct and allow to download via header() file_get_content() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473932/browser-html-force-download-of-image-from-src-dataimage-jpegbase64

Comment: no chmod whatsoever - because if your webserver can't access it, your webserver can't access it, so your script fails, too. you should instead move your upload folder outside of the document root to make access impossible or secure it with a .htaccess-file to disallow access.

Comment: you are the best, thanks ;)