# Generated Image from html5 canvas could not be saved in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have an html canvas where things are drawn by the users( used [FabricJs](http://fabricjs.com/) ).

In short the issues are(only in Chrome):
a) Right click > Save not working for the snapshot image from the canvas.
b) Sometimes the snapshot image is blank when trying to print.

I have created a testing version at: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Tvr55555/pen/vaOGLg)
Please check in Chrome.

There are 2 button beside the canvas - Download & Print.
Both having different issues - only in Chrome.

When the Download button is clicked an window is opened containing a snapshot 
image of the canvas using - **canvas.toDataURL()**. 
User then can right click on the image and save it.
This works Ok in Firefox(user can right-click -> save the image). 
In chrome the dialog window opens with the image perfectly, but if right click on the image, then after selecting 'Save the Image' - nothing happens.
The image is Ok, you can drag-drop-save it from the dialog window to desktop directly.
But saving from the right-click-menu option does not work.

On 'Download' button click I am calling a function like the following to popup a window with the snapshot in it.

```
function open_dialog() {
  var canvas_image_data = canvas.toDataURL();

  var dlWindow = window.open("", "Download Image", "directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=500, height=500");

  dlWindow.document.write('<img src="'+canvas_image_data+'" style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;" width="300" height="300"/>');

  return dlWindow;
}
```

When the Print Button is clicked the Dialog with image snapshot is opened and browser's print features is called.
This also works Ok in FireFox, but in chrome - the image is blank in the print preview sometimes. In my testing(in several devices, the ratio is like - missing once in every 3/4 times in the Print button click).
[image]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/clue for the issues!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle, please?

Comment: Please check at: https://codepen.io/Tvr55555/pen/vaOGLg

Comment: You want to save canvas as image?

Comment: I am taking a snapshot of the canvas using canvas.toDataURL() method.

Comment: for example: <img src="{ canvas.toDataURL() }"/> , here an image is shown(snapshot of the canvas), but it cannot be right-click and saved to disk from chrome browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came from another question with exactly the same problem (image async load).

Altough you create an image with a data URL, the image still fires its `load` event. I mean, you are calling print **before** the image is loaded ([the browser loads images in an asynchronous way, even with data URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776670/should-setting-an-image-src-to-data-url-be-available-immediately)). You must wait for the image throw the `load` event and then call the print method.

Here you have a dirty patch, so you get the idea: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMbYEX

Comment: thanks @Jorge Fuentes González for the solution. It resolved the print preview missing issue.

Comment: I am still searching to resolve the primary issue(a) - not being able to right-click, then save the image. I have no clue yet - why chrome is not letting a loaded image(preview ok, can be drag-drop & saved) to be saved :(

Comment: @TanvirAhmed You can use this to allow the user download the image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473932/browser-html-force-download-of-image-from-src-dataimage-jpegbase64

Comment: Thank you very much @Jorge Fuentes González, I really appreciate your help. I finally resolved the remaining download issue from the provided examples of yours. I loaded the download window as follow - <a download="img.png" href="'+canvas_image_data+'"><img src="'+canvas_image_data+'" style="..." /></a> and it worked Ok both in Chrome & Firefox :)

Comment: @TanvirAhmed yay! ^^