# Create and save a file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file, dialog, save

I have data that I want to write to a file, and open a file dialog for the user to choose where to save the file.  It would be great if it worked in all browsers, but it has to work in Chrome.  I want to do this all client-side.

Basically I want to know what to put in this function:

```
saveFile: function(data)
{
}
```

Where the function takes in data, has the user select a location to save the file, and creates a file in that location with that data.

Using HTML is fine too, if that helps.

Comment: Has been an exact duplicate of [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server) for years.

Answer (score 343):

A very minor improvement of the code by [Awesomeness01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4181717/awesomeness01) (no need for anchor tag) with addition as suggested by [trueimage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430498/trueimage) (support for IE):

```
// Function to download data to a file
function download(data, filename, type) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: type});
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, filename);
    else { // Others
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
                url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
        }, 0); 
    }
}
```

Tested to be working properly in Chrome, FireFox and IE10.

In Safari, the data gets opened in a new tab and one would have to manually save this file.

Comment: Specifically which version of IE?

Comment: @Soren It currently does not work in any version of IE, as far as I know. Safari might not have it either, but I don't work with those and I would have to look it up.

Comment: Not working in Google Chrome. I am thinking to make this as a bookmarklet
`javascript:function download(text, name, type) {
  var a = document.getElementById("content");
  var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = name;
}`

Comment: This is not working in IE 11.0.9600.18426, but it is working in Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m. Any ideas to get this working in IE 11?

Comment: To get it working in IE 11 and Chrome I replaced the a.href line with: if(window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                 window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, name);
              }
          else {
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          }

Comment: Seems to me like `var a = document.createElement("a")` should be in the `else` branch, otherwise IE10+ will create but not remove the anchor (`<a>`) element.

Comment: This solution should be really accepted. I have created a repo for anyone who wants to try this solution. https://github.com/slavede/ajax-js-download It uses mentioned logic. I've tested in latest Chrome, FF, Edge and Safari.

Comment: Seems not to work in Safari, just nothing happens (no save)

Comment: Just to make your code a little neater, do `var file = new Blob([data], {type});`

Comment: How to set location in this script when download?

Comment: It doesn't work in Chrome for Mobile.

Comment: Can we specify which folder to download to?

Comment: What can we use for `type`?

Comment: This is a great solution. I tried the code and find it still works without `document.body.appendChild(a)` and `setTimeout()`. The final code is `var a = document.createElement("a"), url = URL.createObjectURL(file); a.href = url;  a.download = filename; a.click(); URL.revokeObjectURL(url);` Are there any drawbacks?

Answer (score 158):

```js
function download(text, name, type) {
  var a = document.getElementById("a");
  var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = name;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="a">click here to download your file</a>
<button onclick="download('file text', 'myfilename.txt', 'text/plain')">Create file</button>
```

And you would then download the file by putting the download attribute on the anchor tag.

The reason I like this better than creating a data url is that you don't have to make a big long url, you can just generate a temporary url.

Comment: @Banjocat You should check if the browser support certain objects. Example detecting: `if("URL"in window&&"createObjectURL"in URL&&"download"in Element.prototype)`: else then you just change the downloading method or notice that the browser doesn't support the needed objects to download the file.

Comment: In firefox this works if you click the link, but if you right click and choose Save Link As... nothing happens.

Comment: Doesn't work in Google Chrome: `Download is disallowed. The frame initiating or instantiating the download is sandboxed, but the flag ‘allow-downloads’ is not set. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280 for more details.`

Comment: @posfan12 Try implementing it in your own page, SO renders the code snippet in an iframe, which is not allowed to download files without the allow-downloads flag.

Answer (score 43):

Choosing the location to save the file before creating it is not possible. But it is possible, at least in Chrome, to generate files using just JavaScript. Here is an old example of mine of creating a CSV file. The user will be prompted to download it. This, unfortunately, does not work well in other browsers, especially IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS CSV</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="b">export to CSV</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function exportToCsv() {
            var myCsv = "Col1,Col2,Col3\nval1,val2,val3";

            window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(myCsv));
        }

        var button = document.getElementById('b');
        button.addEventListener('click', exportToCsv);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I use this it opens a new tab with the text in it, it doesn't open a file dialog window.

Comment: @user1756980 - Yes. You would need to "Save To File" from that new tab.

Comment: It depends on the browser, os, etc. At the time I wrote the answer, a csv data url in Chrome would pop a save dialog

Comment: @JesseChisholm you can do that in javascript. just create an anchor tag in a variable and put the download attribute on it (like so: a.download = "downloadname.txt") and then clicking it with a.click().

Answer (score 17):

For latest browser, like Chrome, you can use the [File API as in this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/):

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024 /*5MB*/, saveFile, errorHandler);
```

Comment: I think [this code snippet](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-writing) would be closer to the asker's intention.

Comment: See here for evidence of it's deadness: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014AprJun/0010.html

Answer (score 13):

```js
function SaveBlobAs(blob, file_name) {
    if (typeof navigator.msSaveBlob == "function")
        return navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, file_name);

    var saver = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "a");
    var blobURL = saver.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob), 
        body = document.body;

    saver.download = file_name;

    body.appendChild(saver);
    saver.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));
    body.removeChild(saver);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Tried this in the console, and it works.

```
var aFileParts = ['<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'];
var oMyBlob = new Blob(aFileParts, {type : 'text/html'}); // the blob
window.open(URL.createObjectURL(oMyBlob));
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this purely in Javascript. Javascript running on browsers does not have enough permission yet (there have been proposals) due to security reasons.

Instead, I would recommend using [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify):

> A tiny javascript + Flash library that enables the creation and download of text files without server interaction.

You can see a simple demo [here](http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html) where you supply the content and can test out saving/cancelling/error handling functionality.

Comment: Obsolete answer

Answer (score 4):

[StreamSaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js) is an alternative to save very large files without having to keep all data in the memory.
In fact it emulates everything the server dose when saving a file but all client side with service worker.

You can either get the writer and manually write Uint8Array's to it or pipe a binary readableStream to the writable stream

There is a few [example](https://jimmywarting.github.io/StreamSaver.js/example.html) showcasing:

- How to save multiple files as a zip
- piping a readableStream from eg `Response` or `blob.stream()` to StreamSaver
- manually writing to the writable stream as you type something
- or recoding a video/audio

Here is an example in it's simplest form:

```
const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream('filename.txt')

new Response('StreamSaver is awesome').body
  .pipeTo(fileStream)
  .then(success, error)
```

If you want to save a blob you would just convert that to a readableStream

```
new Response(blob).body.pipeTo(...) // response hack
blob.stream().pipeTo(...) // feature reference
```

Comment: This looks like a very useful library. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

For Chrome and Firefox, I have been using a purely JavaScript method.

(My application cannot make use of a package such as `Blob.js` because it is served from a special engine: a DSP with a WWWeb server crammed in and little room for anything at all.)

```
function FileSave(sourceText, fileIdentity) {
    var workElement = document.createElement("a");
    if ('download' in workElement) {
        workElement.href = "data:" + 'text/plain' + "charset=utf-8," + escape(sourceText);
        workElement.setAttribute("download", fileIdentity);
        document.body.appendChild(workElement);
        var eventMouse = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        eventMouse.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        workElement.dispatchEvent(eventMouse);
        document.body.removeChild(workElement);
    } else throw 'File saving not supported for this browser';
}
```

Notes, caveats, and weasel-words:

- I have had success with this code in both Chrome and Firefox clients running in Linux (Maipo) and Windows (7 and 10) environments.
- However, if `sourceText` is larger than a MB, Chrome sometimes (only sometimes) gets stuck in its own download without any failure indication; Firefox, so far, has not exhibited this behavior. The cause might be some blob limitation in Chrome. Frankly, I just don't know; if anybody has any ideas how to correct (or at least detect), please post. If the download anomaly occurs, when the Chrome browser is closed, it generates a diagnostic such as
  [image: Chrome browser diagnostic]
- This code is not compatible with Edge or Internet Explorer; I have not tried Opera or Safari.