# how to export csv file with filename

Tags: javascript, csv, export, filenames, encodeuricomponent

I want to export the exist data into csv file. I try to use this code:

```
var uriContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(data);
var myWindow = window.open(uriContent);
myWindow.focus();
```

it works but I can design filename. I can only get the dialog with name like "MVeAnkW8.csv.part" which I don't know where the name come from.

How can I assign filename in the first dialog? Thanks in advance.

**update:**

I am now using rails. Actually I have a method in server side names export_to_csv. In end of this method, I use code like that:

```
  send_data(csv_string,
  :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8;',
  :filename => "myfile.csv")
```

It works and I can specify the file name.
For now, I want to use ajax to get more csv files(that is the reason why I want to use javascript, because a normal http request can only get one file to be downloaded).

I use js code like that:

```
$.post("export_to_csv",
 function(data) {
 var uriContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(data);
     var myWindow = window.open(uriContent);
     myWindow.focus();});
```

It get the data from server side and I try to transfer it into csv. I can get a file but can't specify the file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know, you can specify the filename only in chrome 14+.
Take a look at this question: [Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)

Update!

If you want to download multiple csv files "at once", you can zip them together, or save each file on the server separately (each file now has a url that points to it - if you place them inside the 'www' folder). 
Then send the file names and their path/url to the client via ajax (use a json encoded list for example).
In the ajax callback function: take the list of the files and open each file-url in a separate popup.