# Export HTML table to Excel but select a name for the file

Tags: jquery, excel

I'm using this function

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
, template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
, base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
, format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p];      }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
 }
})()
```

Here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/insin/cmewv/

In that example, they change the name of the worksheet, but is there any way to change the name of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answers at: [Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)

Basically, there's no way to do this with JavaScript. If the file is being downloaded with an `<a>` link, you can specify a filename using the `download` attribute, but [this is not widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) (right now just Chrome and BB10).

Comment: This definitily worked! Well, almost. I need support for all browsers but the download attribute worked perfectly on Chrome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me :

```
 $scope.exportData = (function() {
              var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
                , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
                , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
                , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
              return function(table, name) {
                if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
                var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
                //window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                    link.download = "filename.xls";
                    link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
                    link.click();
              }
            })()
```

Answer (score 2):

works for me too. I add a prompt to take download name dynamicly

```
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    //window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    var downloadName = prompt("write some explanation", "table");
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = downloadName + ".xls";
    link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    link.click();
```