# Suggest filename for data: URI

Tags: javascript, html

I generate an SVG string in JavaScript.

I serve it to the user with:

```
window.open("data:image/svg+xml," + svg_xml_string);
```

When you try to save that page in Chrome it will suggest to save as *download.svg* is there anyway I can change the default filename of the download?

---

I tried:

```
data:image/svg+xml;headers=Content-Disposition%3Aattachment%3Bfilename%3D%22suggest.svg%22,...
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri (unresolved)

Comment: Also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages _"Data URIs do not carry a filename as a normal linked file would. When saving, a default filename for the specified MIME type is generally used."_

Answer (score -1):

This is solved in some, [very new](http://caniuse.com/download) browsers.  The question linked in the comments also mentions the Opera-specific proposed extension you brought up, but I think your best bet is to use the `<a download="...">` attribute and suggest that users with older browsers set the filename for themselves when downloading.

Comment: Nope, the download attribute doesn't work with the Data URI scheme.