# download image from amazon s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to download an image from amazon s3 bucket which i have saved earlier in the same.

I am using jquery to download the image but instead of downloading it open the image.

this is my sample amazon s3 bucket url

https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/dev-chn/pm/20150822142439-Penguins.jpg

This is my jquery code

```
$.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'), {
 preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your download, please wait...",
 failMessageHtml: "There was a problem downloading, please try again later."
});
```

am using jquery ui download plugin

could anyone help me?

Comment: What's the Jquery code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download image with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311645/download-image-with-javascript)

Comment: check out my solution using the `aws-sdk`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53270004/9009196