# how to make an auto download image in javascript by setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

```
<a id="download" href="link of your file">click here to download the file</a>.

<script>
    var downloadTimeout = setTimeout (
        function() {
            window.location = document.getElementById('download').href;
        }, 4000);
</script>
```

This is not what I want, I need the image will be automatically downloaded when 
    the time is stop by setTimeout but I can't get it. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: you're not binding the function....

Comment: how? can you give me some idea to create a automatically download the image in canvas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156686/how-to-start-automatic-download-of-a-file-in-internet-explorer 
refer this link it might helpful

Comment: Thanks for the link. but this is not what i meant sir. I need the canvas to download as image when the time is up using setTimeout().

Comment: see kornel's and kikito's answer there.

Comment: do you have a link?

Comment: No `canvas` element appears at `html` at Question?

Comment: that was a sample sir. I'm just getting an idea in that script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download image with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311645/download-image-with-javascript)

Comment: I want the image to download automatically sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using HTML5. To download image, add `download` property to your link. Note that this doesn't work in some browsers. You can try it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q9h7wcL2/2/).

```
<a href = "yourImage.png" download = "customName.png" id = "download">Click here to download image</a>
<canvas></canvas>
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){
    downloadCanvas();
  }, 4E3);

  function downloadImage(){
    document.getElementById('download').click();
  }

  function downloadCanvas(){
    var a = document.getElementById('download');
    var b = a.href;
    a.href = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].toDataURL();
    downloadImage();
    a.href = b;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't really have an idea in where to put your code sir, 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"yourImage.png\"

Comment: @jovendiojoy. It is really unclear what you are exactly asking for? If you want to download file `yourImage.png` after timeout, then you need to edit headers of that image making it `ocet-stream`, so browser will download it instead of displaying it. Also, why you want to use a canvas? Canvas has nothing to do with downloading image.

Comment: can you give me some code on where to put that? I really don't don't where to put that. sorry. Please.

Comment: @jovendiojoy I edited my answer. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: sorry sir. I'm not using php for my application that I want to create. now I'm create a face detection and my only problem is that how I can download automatically download the image. by the way Thank you.

Comment: @jovendiojoy. You can do it only using Javascript, but it doesn't work on some browsers. Check my answer.

Comment: what if I will download the canvas as image?

Comment: @jovendiojoy. If you found what you have been looking for and my answer helped you, consider accepting it.

Comment: @jovendiojoy. By accepting answer I mean pressing little "accept" arrow on the right side of my answer. It will help other users find it useful.

Comment: this doesn't work