# jQuery Download Images to Folder

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking at this question [Download image with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311645/download-image-with-javascript) which shows how to download an image.

I want to be able to do something similar but more automated. I would like to navigate to an imgur page, enter some search parameters then use jQuery to download any .jpeg or .png

I have the basic layout

```
navigate to imgur and search
find all .jpeg and .png in page
run code similar to other question to download
```

What I want to know, is can I specify a specific folder to save the images to?
Can I automate the click of the Save button?

If this is not possible in pure jQuery/javascript my other choice is to default to using iMacros with some javascript mixed in, I would however like to avoid this.

Comment: Do you want to use jQuery/JavaScript on a website? Then your project cannot be realized, if you target a common browser. Or do you want to build a Node.js project?

Comment: I am not sure what a node.js project is, I was just looking at a script to run in Chrome or Firefox's console

Comment: TL;DR: After installing Node.js you can execute JavaScript from a console (e.g. by calling "node hello.js"). Alternatively you may also use something like CasperJS to access websites by JavaScript and download stuff.

Comment: So it is a stand alone JS environment? If I understand correctly this is something I want to eventually use. However for time constraints I will be using iMacros

Comment: Yes, it is a JavaScript runtime environment. You can download it from https://nodejs.org/ and after installing it, you can execute JS files by calling e.g. "node hello.js". As a hello world example, hello.js could contain "console.log("Hello World");".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using *only* JavaScript.

A user's interaction will *always* be required in order to save a file. Imagine the mess we'd be in if that weren't the case... Viruses everywhere!

Comment: I figured as much. I have a python program which downloads images, I assume javascript is also blocked from running external applications?

Comment: Yea, that's not possible either. (Unless you install some browser plugin, maybe)

Comment: Well thank you for confirming that for me. I suppose iMacros + JS it is!