# Javascript download attribute not working when saving image dataUrl

Tags: javascript, download, data-url

I am using chrome.

This is my code.

```
var save = document.createElement('a');
save.href = fileURL;
save.download = fileName;
alert(save.download);
save.click();
```

It works well but it doesn't change the image name. It saves as "download.png".

What is wrong?

Comment: If your problem is what I think it is, this is the answer for it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6943481/240443

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to see what `fileURL` and `fileName` are set to but I am guessing that is your problem. In Firefox and Chrome you have to use the relative path to the image. It will not work on remote images.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) says:

> In Firefox 20 this attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin.

I have tested this in Chrome and Firefox and it only works if you use the relative path to the image:

```
 save.href = "images/wonky-download-121938718712348891912.jpg";
 save.download = "coolName.jpg";
```

I say ralative path because using `mysite.com/image.jpg` didn't work while `image.jpg` did.

**Update**

[whatwg.org](http://developers.whatwg.org/links.html#downloading-resources) says:

> In cross-origin situations, the download attribute has to be combined
>   with the Content-Disposition HTTP header, specifically with the
>   attachment disposition type, to avoid the user being warned of
>   possibly nefarious activity.

Comment: This is very rare right answer, regarding this topic which explains why suggested file name does not work (due to different origin). For me currently works only in Edge.