# Google's downloadDataURI in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I use Google's [`downloadDataURI`](https://code.google.com/p/download-data-uri/source/browse/trunk/js/download-data-uri.js?r=2) function to download the PNG exported by a [Google Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/771/).
In Chrome is working well, but in Firefox instead of downloading, replaces the html content with the PNG that is generated.

Anybody knows how to fix that behavior in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this doesn't look like it is a Google project at all, but just a project somebody put up on the free Google Code hosting service (+ appspot)

What it does:

- It checks if the browser is "webkit", and if not just changes the location to the data URI. This is exactly what happens in firefox and why the PNG is displayed instead of being downloaded.
- Otherwise, it will construct a hidden `<form>` and `<input>` and post it to some random HTTP appspot server. And this does not sound very secure. The people running the appspot instance could log requests and/or a man-in-the-middle attacker could passively monitor the unencrypted transmission.

Honestly, I wouldn't use this service, ever, because I cannot trust the transmission channel, and I cannot trust the people behind it.

Instead, consider using [`<a download=... >`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download), e.g. see [Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)