# specify the extension svg, file downloaded using data: image / octet-stream

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a page with dynamically generated SVG. I call the save file dialog using `data:image/octet-stream`. The client would not recognise the URL as an inline-able resource, and prompt a download dialog.

```
var dataImageUri = "data:image/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(svg);
  window.open(dataImageUri);
```

But then the file is saved without an extension. Expansion and name need to register manually. 
Can I ask how that extension and name for the file?

Comment: You could try using the correct MIME type for SVG: `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: You could use the html5 `download` attribute, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri.

Comment: You could try using the correct MIME type for SVG: image/svg+xml - it's not saving the SVG on the local filesystem, this opens the SVG in it's own page.   Using html5 download attribute does not suit me to structure my project.