# Custom name for blob URL

Tags: javascript

We have an application that gets some input parameters and sends them to the back end where they get processed. The processing result is a PDF file that we want to open in a new tab.

The code doing this looks similar to the below:

```
let response = await myService.getDocument();
let file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
```

Everything works fine but the URL in the browser shows some random generated string as below:

```
blob:http://localhost:3000/85cad96e-e44e-a1f9-db97a96ed3fe
```

Obviously this does not look very good to the end user and we would prefer to display something which is meaningful to the user, say something like:

```
blob:ftp://localhost:3000/my_document_name_or_whatever
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Short answer, **You can't**.

This is an address that points to the browser's memory, where it has stored your blob, or a pointer to the original file in case of user uploaded file through the input type=file.

This is somehow by design. You can create multiple of these blobURLs from the same Blob. If they were to use a filename as URI, you couldn't.

Theoretically, it should be possible for you to dynamically create a page that would redirect to the BlobURI, and you could name this redirection page as you which. But this is just theory, I never tried to do it myself.

A rough proof of concept can be seen in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c9uLupGvWaSsRxV0pIna?p=preview), obviously, you'll need to generate *blobRename.html* dynamically, and change its name to the one you want, and also force it's content-header so that the browser thinks it's an html page if you want to get rid of the `.html`.
Also note that it doesn't seem to work with pdf files, which need browser plugins to trigger in, but with some more work, it *may* be possible to hack something around.

But anyway, I would just let the random url, your users will get more and more used to it as more and more web apps do use this great API.

Comment: You can set file name, add below
**
downloadLink.href = `${filename}`;**

Comment: Works in Firefox, doesn't work in Chrome sadly.

Answer (score 31):

You can create a link with a [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download) filename specified, then trigger a click to open it:

```
let file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

// create <a> element dynamically
let fileLink = document.createElement('a');
fileLink.href = fileURL;

// suggest a name for the downloaded file
fileLink.download = 'pdf_name';

// simulate click
fileLink.click();
```

Comment: It works nicely if you want to download file, but seems doesn't help if you need to open it on the new tab.

Comment: And how to open in new tab instead of downloading?

Comment: That will download the file, it won't open in a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same and actually you can add a download attribute for the link and that would make the trick on Chrome, I didn't tried in IE so far.

```
<a href="urlBlobData" download="fileTest.csv">Your file</a>
```

and this is an example with Angular 5

```
<a #link *ngIf="urlBlobData" [href]="urlData" target="_blank" rel="noopener" download="fileTest.csv">Your file</a>
```

Hope that work for you as well.

Comment: How to provide ngIf and download attribute's values? 
I am getting binary format file in an api response, `target='_blank'` in html its still not working, I tried removing download attribute too, what else is needed?

Answer (score 2):

## Answer for 2023

This is a frustrating problem for developers who want to generate a PDF inside the browser with something like `pdf-lib` while retaining control over the default filename offered to the user when they click the download/save button on the browser's built-in PDF viewer.

### Back story

I wasted a bunch of time trying to get `PDF.js` to work in Svelte so it looks like the the default PDF viewer with just the download button overridden. I had one problem after the other. Everything seemed stacked against me and there were old Stack Overflow answers and blog posts casually mentioning their project that uses `PDF.js` to display PDFs. Things had changed (like the introduction of a top-level await that Svelte doesn't like and a change in philosophy about the release of the default viewer's source code). Was I really going to have to generate the files on the server just so I have control over the filename? That's not acceptable.

### Overview

Thankfully, you can now solve this problem with the [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) in combination with the [Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). They are widely supported by modern browsers, so there shouldn't be any issues in terms of compatibility. IE doesn't support it, obviously, but that's not really worth mentioning.

**Unfortunately, this won't work well in Chromium-based browsers because of a [years-old bug](https://crbug.com/468227)**

This technique allows you to leverage browser-based rendering while maintaining control over the filename with the caveat that Chromium will only download the file directly from the server. Please star the bug report if you want to see this fixed in Chromium.

### Cache API

Basically, you add the document to a cache and assign it a URL on your server that is won't get in the way of any other files, then set an `iframe`'s `src` to the URL once the cache finishes accepting it. That stores it where your service worker can find it and tells the browser to go looking for it there. Since you define the URL, you also control the filename (it's the last segment of the pathname).

### Service Worker API

Then you create and register a service worker that checks the cache to see if the file exists before fetching it from the Internet. If it's in your cache, it's because you put it there, so don't worry about it getting confused with random files. When the browser goes looking for the file that you stored a moment ago, it'll find and return it as if you downloaded it off the Internet.

### Conclusion

Service workers are easy to register in SvelteKit just by creating a file in the correct location, but it really doesn't take much to create and register one with any other framework. You just have to keep in mind that the browser will try to hang onto the service worker, forcing you to clear your site data when you want to make changes to it. So it's best to avoid putting code in there that might change frequently.

Answer (score 1):

There's another possible solution that can be explored but it has it's own issues. You can actually store your blob url in the browser cookie storage and then retrieve it from another tab and when you create the shared worker it will connect to the same worker. The caveat here is that your blob can disappear while your cookie value is still set so when a new worker gets initialized it will silently fail. There may be ways to mitigate this if you tested somehow to see if the worker script was running successfully and if it's not, erase the cookie and recreate the blob. However there doesn't seem to be a reliable way to know if workers are running from the main thread so this would be tricky, but I suspect doable if you use some delays/timeouts and wait for an echo from the worker for example.

Answer (score -2):

You can add/pass file name by adding below, however it will download the file instead of opening it in new tab, but at least user will get a properly named file,

```
//import and inject Renderer2
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

let downloadLink = this.renderer.createElement('a');

//this converts binary data to a pdf
downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: 'application/pdf' }));

//you can pass filename here
   downloadLink.setAttribute('download', filename); 
   document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
   downloadLink.click();
```

Comment: Just curious, why is this answer given negative rating? This worked for me, after trying lots of different things for whole two days. It might be helpful for a person facing same scenario as me.

Comment: What is downloadLink, and how does it relate to the original question?

Comment: @Pinka it gets downvoted because it doesn't solve the problem. Your solution downloads the document (I assume PDF) instead of showing it in a new tab (with ultimately the correct PDF name).

Comment: @Dankas Yes, it does download the pdf instead of opening it in new tab, but as mentioned, I just posted the solution of how we can pass/set the name of the file as the original question had that issue of not being able to set name. It is just a workaround to set name. 
Sorry, I'll update my answer to inform same.

Comment: @DanKas Have you found the solution for the same?

Comment: @Pinka also your answer is a little late. Other answers already mentioned this solution years ago

Answer (score -3):

Taken from [How to set a file name using window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034754/how-to-set-a-file-name-using-window-open/7034818#7034818)

Granted this is downloading the file not opening in another tab.

```
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = myBlob;
downloadLink.download = "myFile.pdf";

document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

Answer (score -4):

You can simply add a `setTimeout` to change the page title after the blob has been loaded in the new tab like this -

```
newTab.location.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
setTimeout(function() {
    newTab.document.title = blob.name;
}, 10);
```

Comment: `SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object`

Comment: updating title wont work