# Download excel file in angular 7 using a blob url

Tags: excel, angular

I am trying to download excel file in my angular 7 app using the mime type "**data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,**" but when I'm trying to open the downloaded file it throws me some error saying - http://prntscr.com/ur1nc4.

Here is what I've done inorder to download the file

```
const filePath = "https://bviewstorage.blob.core.windows.net/9be306d9-acb1-4f25-a54f-5126e021ec6d/hrm/aabe5bd4-940a-4246-979c-581fdaa45808/Client_export_1592830934796-94f5d780-4007-4ae6-b802-53f4fe5509f2.xlsx"
const linkSource = "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet," + filePath;
        const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.href = linkSource;
        downloadLink.download = "ExcelTemplate" + this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd") + ".xlsx";
        downloadLink.click();
```

I've even try to download the file path "xls" MIME type but still it throws same error.

Please let me know the ways to download the excel file.

Comment: Is there any difference to that question?
https://stackoverflow.com/q/1066452/6548154

Comment: I've tried that solution also@A_A but it still throws me same error when I'm trying to open the downloaded excel file

Comment: There are many solutions there, which have you tried? For instance `window.location = 'https://bviewstorage.blob.core.windows.net/9be306d9-acb1-4f25-a54f-5126e021ec6d/hrm/aabe5bd4-940a-4246-979c-581fdaa45808/Client_export_1592830934796-94f5d780-4007-4ae6-b802-53f4fe5509f2.xlsx'` worked for me on firefox

Answer (score 1):

```
function downloadFile(filePath) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = filePath;
  link.onclick = function() {
    document.body.innerText = "Downloading";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.innerText = "";
    }, 2000);
  }
  link.download = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  link.click();
}

downloadFile("https://bviewstorage.blob.core.windows.net/9be306d9-acb1-4f25-a54f-5126e021ec6d/hrm/aabe5bd4-940a-4246-979c-581fdaa45808/Client_export_1592830934796-94f5d780-4007-4ae6-b802-53f4fe5509f2.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `appenchild` and it should work.

```
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.click();
```

For IE do it like this:

```
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
  window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(url, filename);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.I've tried as you said but it still shows the same error when I'm trying to open the downloaded file

Answer (score 0):

```
const filePath = "https://bviewstorage.blob.core.windows.net/9be306d9-acb1-4f25-a54f-5126e021ec6d/hrm/aabe5bd4-940a-4246-979c-581fdaa45808/Client_export_1592830934796-94f5d780-4007-4ae6-b802-53f4fe5509f2.xlsx"

if(window) {
  window.open(filePath);
}
```

As your file is not secure it can be download with the above code. window.open opens a new browser window which will download the file from blob directly.

Comment: Thank you for your response.If I've done something as you said then the downloaded file name is taken automatically from blob path but I want the downloaded file name to be custom(I need to provide the file name based on conditions)

Comment: Answer is simple the thing you were trying do is some how not possible. I have same requirement downloading a xlxs file form blob. I have searched for N no of solutions ended up with below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947735/custom-name-for-blob-url

Comment: There is one way you can do it.

You need help of a backend API which can provide you a blob. The Backend API should  extract the file from blobURL and it should return you the blob content. 

The API should be POST and should have content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Answer (score 0):

Extension to comment above solution

```js
 submitForm(): void {
      this.myFormPost.nativeElement.submit();
  }
```

```html
<form
  ngNoForm
  #myFormPost
  name="myFormPost"
  action="{{ backend API Here }}"
  method="POST"
  target="_blank"
>
  <input type="hidden" [name]="'token'" [value]="use this to pass token" />
</form>
<a
  href="javascript:void(0);"
  (click)="submitForm()"
  ><i class="fas fa-download" *ngIf="isDownload"></i>Download File</a
>
```

Angular Code to handle blob data download.