# javascript blob name showing in pdf file

Tags: javascript, pdf

I receive base64 pdf string from the server.
I need to show the correct pdf file name instead of the blob name.

**It must be in the new tab**

```
      const b64 = data.fileData;
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.innerHTML = "Download PDF file";
      link.download = data.fileName;
      link.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64," + b64;
      const byteString = atob(link.href.split(",")[1]);

      const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
      const ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
      for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      const blob = new Blob([ab], { type: "application/pdf" });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(url);
```

this is what it's showing in my url:

```
localhost:8080/d03908a1-6bbc-49e8-929d-e0c4cd313095
```

**I need to change the name to my custom name like myPdf.pdf**

[image: I need to change the name]

what have a tried and also not working:

```
 // const newWindow = window.open('', data.fileName, "width=800,height=1200");
      // if (newWindow) {
      //     setTimeout( () => {
      //         const dataUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      //         const title = newWindow.document.createElement('title');
      //         const iframe = newWindow.document.createElement('iframe');
  
      //         title.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.fileName));
      //         newWindow.document.head.appendChild(title);
  
      //         iframe.setAttribute('src', dataUrl);
      //         iframe.setAttribute('width', "100%");
      //         iframe.setAttribute('height', "100%");
  
      //         newWindow.document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  
      //         setTimeout( () => {
      //             // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL
      //             window.URL.revokeObjectURL(dataUrl);
      //         }, 100);
      //     }, 100);
      // }
```

is some has there code ?
https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf

this is working but i can't download and to nothing:
https://base64.guru/developers/javascript/examples/decode-pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom name for BLOB URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41947735/custom-name-for-blob-url)

Comment: This is what is showing d03908a1-6bbc-49e8-929d-e0c4cd313095

Comment: and i need to change it to "mypdf.pdf"

Comment: Custom name for BLOB URL  - this is was 4 years ago, i thought that we can do something about it

Answer (score 0):

The below code works perfectly if you want to download a file, But if you need to open the file in a new tab I'm pretty sure that it is not possible.

Try something like below :

```js
var file = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

// create <a> tag dinamically
var fileLink = document.createElement('a');
fileLink.href = fileURL;

// it forces the name of the downloaded file
fileLink.download = 'pdf_name';

// triggers the click event
fileLink.click();
```