# How to specify the download file name in FrontEnd

Tags: javascript

**UPDATE:**

[Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

I am trying to implement click a button and download file from its DataURL.

Currently, since the Chrome has restricted the old way such as building `<a>` link which throws error like:

> Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: ....

The solution I found is open new window with iframe and set the DataURL as its `src`

```
let jpgWindow = window.open("", "_blank")
var html = "<html><body><iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/jpeg;base64, "+ theDataURL+"'></iframe></body></html>";
jpgWindow.document.write(html)
```

When I click the button, the download works, but the picture is downloaded with filename "download", **there is no way I can specify what file name I want it default to.**

Any thought?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33542499/4092887

Answer (score 2):

Look into `window.URL.createObjectURL` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

```
const blob = new Blob(['array of data in your file'], {type : 'text/rtf'});
const anchor = document.createElement('a');

anchor.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
anchor.download = 'the-file-name.txt';
anchor.click();
```