# How can I set name of download file from export html to xls?

Tags: javascript

Everyone, I want to set name file for export from html to xls.
When I export it get **download.xls** file when I get download file another name like **inventory.xls** Please help

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,', 
   template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft- 
    com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft- 
    com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 
    <head> 
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets> 
    <x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name> 
    <x:WorksheetOptions> 
    <x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet> 
    </x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta 
    http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF- 
    8"/> 
    </head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>', 
   base64 = function(s) { 
     return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) 
   },
   format = function(s, c) { 
     return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, 
     function(m, p) { 
        return c[p]; 
     })
   }
   return function(table, name) {
      if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
      var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: 
      table.innerHTML}
      window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
   }
 })()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you envisage the user interacting with your page.

If you can somehow tie this functionality to a link or a button, you can use the `download` attribute,

```html
<a download='FileName' href='your_url'>
```

which simultaneously suggests a filename for the downloaded resource, and tells the browser that that URI specified is specifically for downloading, rather than navigation, which circumvents you having to use the

```
window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
```

part of your code.

Otherwise, this sort of functionality is usually delivered by servers, and being able to set the HTTP headers of the response. e.g. in PHP:

```php
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="July Report.pdf"');
```

---

Your function doesn't seem to rely on any dynamic components or inputs, so I would suggest modifying your function to run on page ready, to set the `href` attribute of a link in the page. Assuming you only ever need one button.

HTML:

```html
<a download="inventory.xls" id="download-link" href=""> Download </a>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  // Inlining these for simplicity. If you need multiple tables and download links on a page, 
  // you can always pull these out later
  let table = 'testTable';
  let name = 'W3C Example Table';

  let uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,', 
   template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft- 
    com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft- 
    com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> 
    <head> 
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets> 
    <x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name> 
    <x:WorksheetOptions> 
    <x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet> 
    </x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta 
    http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF- 
    8"/> 
    </head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>', 
   base64 = function(s) { 
     return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) 
   },
   format = function(s, c) { 
     return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, 
     function(m, p) { 
        return c[p]; 
     })
   }

   if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
   var ctx = {
      worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', 
      table: table.innerHTML
   }
   document.getElementById("download-link").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
 })()
```

Obviously I don't know how this is intended to be used, my code will not necessarily work verbatim. But hopefully that helps

Comment: Please recomment me and this is my button link `<input type="button" @click="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')" `

Comment: failed for download

Comment: Seems to be working here. https://jsfiddle.net/jz73fbpr/1/. Let me know if you're still having trouble. Might be something else in your code interfering.

Comment: Wonderful, please accept my answer then so this gets closed. Glad I can help :)